# Code golf: Flatten с вставкой дополнительного элемента

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

Обновление: обсуждение завершено, результаты в конце текста вопроса.

---

Обсуждение вопроса ведётся в чате «[Code golf на русском](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf--)».

---

Пускай у нас есть набор лениво вычисляемых последовательностей действительных чисел. Задача состоит в том, чтобы построить также лениво вычисляемую последовательность, конкатенирующую все данные последовательности. Но между каждыми двумя последовательностями нужно ещё вставить среднее арифметическое последнего члена предыдущей, и первого члена следующей последовательности.

Пример: пусть исходные данные таковы:

```
1; 2; 3; 4; 5 // 1 кусок
6; 5; 4; 3    // 2 кусок
              // 3 кусок пустой
-3; -3; -3    // 4 кусок
```

Тогда результирующая последовательность должна быть

```
1; 2; 3; 4; 5;   5.5;    6;  5;  4;  3;      0;      -3; -3; -3
// 1-ая часть  (5 + 6)/2  2-ая часть     (3 + -3)/2    4-я часть
```

Ограничения:

- Нельзя материализовывать последовательности, они имеют право быть очень большими и не влезать в оперативку
- Нельзя повторно вычислять куски последовательностей, т. к. генераторы, которые генерируют эти последовательности, имеют право быть очень медленными.
- Полученная последовательность должна быть ленивой, нельзя ничего вычислять заранее.

Код на C#, реализующий подобное, может быть таким:

```
IEnumerable<double> FlattenWithInsertedValues(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> seqs)
{
    double? firstAddend = null;
    foreach (var seq in seqs)
    {
        double? lastInThisSeq = null;
        foreach (var v in seq)
        {
            if (firstAddend != null)
            {
                yield return (firstAddend.Value + v) / 2;
                firstAddend = null;
            }
            yield return v;
            lastInThisSeq = v;
        }
        if (lastInThisSeq != null)
            firstAddend = lastInThisSeq;
    }
}
```

Этот код откровенно прямолинеен, некрасив и императивен. Существует ли более изящное решение? Любители функциональных языков, разумеется, получают в данном вопросе фору на старте, т. к. в остальных ленивые последовательности не встроены в язык.

Приветствуются красивые решения, не обязательно короткие. Дополнительный плюс за правильную обработку пустых кусков.

Поскольку гольф, пожалуйста, одно решение на ответ. Если есть разные решения, постите отдельным ответом.

---

Для того, чтобы было легче тестировать код, вот тесты на C#:

```
void Test1()
{
    var result = FlattenWithInsertedValues(TestGenerator1());
    foreach (var v in result)
        Console.Write(v + " ");
}

void Test2()
{
    var result = FlattenWithInsertedValues(TestGenerator2());
    Console.Write(result.Count());
}

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> TestGenerator1()
{
    Console.Write("Generating outer seq 1 ");
    yield return Generator(1, 5, 1);
    yield return Generator(1, 0, 2);
    yield return Generator(1, 3, 3);
}

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> TestGenerator2()
{
    Console.Write("Generating outer seq 2 ");
    yield return Generator(1, 5, 1);
    yield return Generator(1, 10000000000000, 2);
}

IEnumerable<double> Generator(double from, double to, int seqNum)
{
    Console.Write($"Generating seq #{seqNum} ");
    for (double curr = from; curr < to; curr += 1)
        yield return curr;
}
```

Они выдают:

Test1:

> Generating outer seq 1 Generating seq #1 1 2 3 4 Generating seq #2 Generating seq #3 2,5 1 2

Test2:

> Generating outer seq 2 Generating seq #1 Generating seq #2

Второй тест может очень долго (я не дождался результата своего), но не должен падать по переполнению памяти.

---

## Результаты:

- Приз зрительских симпатий однозначно достаётся [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518602/10105), который показал, что генераторы, ленивость и функциональные фишки вполне реализуемы на таком близком к металлу языке как C, и не ограничены функциональными языками.
- Решения [@Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518703/10105) (ES6), [@D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518697/10105) (Ruby), [@tonal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518462/10105) (Python), [@pavel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518360/10105) (C++) по сути повторяют идею из исходного вопроса, хотя и в более изящной форме. Эти решения также заслуженно получили высокие оценки.
- Прекрасная алгоритмическая идея с энумерацией придумана [@kmv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518377/10105) (F#) и повторно реализована [@tonal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518824/10105) (Python) и ещё раз [@tonal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518969/10105) (теперь Haskell). Мне кажется, решения, основанные на этой идее, остались недооценёнными.
- Отдельной строкой идут решения с паттерн-мэтчингом на Хаскеле ([@tonal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518354/10105), [@Pavel Mayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518846/10105), снова [@tonal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519186/10105)) и Clojure ([@D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519221/10105)), которые выглядят неожиданно просто и легко (за счёт сложности реализации самого паттерн-мэтчинга для ленивых последовательностей). Это, пожалуй, самые правильные решения в смысле простоты и понятности кода. Поэтому самое популярное решение из них принято в качестве ответа.

  (Как оказалось, паттерн-мэтчинг ленивых последовательностей [есть и в F#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1749658/276994), но решения с ним никто не предложил.)
- Ещё красивая идея — явный конечный автомат на Clojure ([@D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518672/10105)). LISP показал, что он ещё может.
- Ещё была реализация на языке Julia, которая, к сожалению, удалена автором решения.

**Огромное спасибо** всем, кто принимал участие в обсуждении и предлагал собственные решения! Надеюсь, участникам сайта будет настолько же приятно и поучительно читать ваши решения и комментарии, насколько и мне.

Comment: Метка 'код-гольф', правильно ли понимаю что выигрывает ответ с наименьшим количеством символов?

Comment: @edem, не совсем :-)

Comment: @D-side: Они не должны ни на что влиять. Внесу в вопрос, да.

Comment: @edem: «Приветствуются красивые решения, не обязательно короткие».

Comment: Так может всё-таки метку 'код-турнир' или 'вопрос-турнир', потому что у "гольфа" правила всё-таки весьма однозначные.

Comment: @edem: Надо будет обсудить в чате.

Comment: Что-то получилось: "пишем одинаковые итераторы на всех языках".

Comment: @Qwertiy одинаковые? Посмотрите решения на Haskell ;)

Comment: Для обсуждения открыта комната в чате: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf--

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На Haskell, втупую:

```
flatten :: [[Float]] -> [Float]
flatten [] = []
flatten [y] = y
flatten ([]:xs) = flatten xs
flatten (y:[]:xs) = flatten $ y:xs
flatten ([y]:(yy:ys):xs) = y : (y + yy)/2 : flatten ((yy:ys):xs)
flatten ((y:ys):zs:xs) = y : flatten (ys:zs:xs)

main = do
  let ls = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4, 3], [-3,  -3, -3]]
  print ls
  let fs = flatten ls
  print fs
```

Здесь используется сопоставление с образцами. Варианты следующие:

1. `flatten [] = []` - На пустой список возвращаем пустой же.
2. `flatten [y] = y` - Во входном списке ровно 1 элемент - его и возвращаем.
3. `flatten ([]:xs) = flatten xs` - Входящий список начинается с пустого. Пропускаем его, а к хвосту `xs` применяем `flatten`.
4. `flatten (y:[]:xs) = flatten $ y:xs` - Во входном списке второй элемент пустой. Пропускаем его, а к списку из головы и хвоста `y:xs` применяем `flatten`.
5. `flatten ([y]:(yy:ys):xs) = y : (y + yy)/2 : flatten ((yy:ys):xs)` - В головном списке остался 1 элемент `y`. Отдаём список из него, его среднего арифметического с первым элементом второй последовательности и хвостом полученным применением `flatten` к списку из второй последовательности и хвоста `(yy:ys):xs`.
6. `flatten ((y:ys):zs:xs) = y : flatten (ys:zs:xs)` - В головном списке несколько элементов. Выдаём список из первого `y` и применения `flatten` к остатку `ys:zs:xs`.

Comment: (1) Пожалуйста, одно решение на ответ. (2) А чем решение на питоне отличается от решения в вопросе по сути?

Comment: 2. Ничем, кроме языка. Я не посмотрел на код C#, когда писал - решение вполне очевидное. :)

Comment: Тогда не могли бы вы (1) добавить ещё один ответ и перенести туда одно из решений; (2) добавить минимальные комментарии?

Answer (score 11):

Вспомним истоки *nix -- *"все есть файл"* и напишем на Си

```
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sysexits.h>

#define DBLRead(fd, d)  (read(fd, d, sizeof(double)) == sizeof(double))
#define DBLWrite(fd, d) (write(fd, d, sizeof(double)) == sizeof(double))

int
flatten (int n, int in[], int out)
{
  int i, j, rc = 0;
  double d0 = NAN, d;

  for (i = 0; !rc && i < n; close(in[i++])) 
    for (j = 0; !rc && DBLRead(in[i], &d); j++) {
      if (!isnan(d0) && j == 0) {
        double m = (d0 + d) / 2;
        if (!DBLWrite(out, &m)) {
          rc = EX_IOERR;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!DBLWrite(out, &d))
        rc = EX_IOERR;
      d0 = d;
    }


  close(out);
  return rc;
}
```

Проверка тоже не слишком длинная

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
generate (int p[2], double from, int step, int n)
{
  if (fork()) {
    close(p[1]);
    return p[0];
  }

  int i, rc = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++, from += step)
    if (!DBLWrite(p[1], &from)) {
      rc = EX_IOERR;
      break;
    }

  exit(rc);
}

#define A_SIZE(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int p1[2], p2[2], p3[2], p4[2], res[2];
  if (pipe(p1) || pipe(p2) || pipe(p3) || pipe(p4) || pipe(res))
    err(EX_OSERR, "pipes");
  int gen_input[4] = {
    generate(p1, 1.0, 1, 5),
    generate(p2, 6.0, -1, 4),
    generate(p3, 1.0, 1, 0),
    generate(p4, -3.0, 0, 3)
  };

  if (!fork()) 
    exit(flatten(A_SIZE(gen_input), gen_input, res[1]));
  close(res[1]);

  double r = 0;
  while(DBLRead(res[0], &r) || (puts(""), 0))
    printf("%g ", r);

  pid_t pid;
  int s;
  while ((pid = wait(&s)) > 0)
    if (!WIFEXITED(s) || WEXITSTATUS(s))
      printf("pid: %d rc = %d\n", (int)pid, WEXITSTATUS(s));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Алгоритм такой же как и в предыдущих C++, C# и Python

Comment: @tonal, зато хаскель абсолютно не понятен. Вы бы для любопытных попробовали как-то расписать, что и почему так там происходит (или популяризация этого чуда Вам претит?)

Comment: Ох, даже на Си возможны генераторы :)

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript ES6

```
function *f(g) {
  for (var x of g) {
    for (var y of x) {
      if (l === +l) { 
        yield (l+y)/2;
        l = '';
      }
      yield y;
    }
    var l = y;
  }
}
```

Тест:

```
for (var x of f([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,5,4,3], [], [-3,-3,-3]])) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Что необычного тут используется?

- ES6 вводит функции-генераторы: `function *f(g) {` с их `yield`.
- Переменные, объявленные при помощи var видны во всей функции, что позволяет использовать `y` вне цикла и `l` раньше `var l`
- `l === +l` - значение строго равно себе же, приведённому к числу. Это означает, что оно число. Тут отсеиваются начальное `undefined` и последующие пустые строки (некая дань гольфу - `''` символа короче чем что-то ещё).

Comment: Тоже хороший язык. А не совсем очевидные действия с `l` подробнее не поясните? Что означает `+l` в сравнении и чему там равна `l` до первого присваивания? (подозреваю, что пока еще просто не существует, т.е. имя есть, а память еще не выделена. Если так, то интересный подход)

Comment: @avp, да, я накидал пару js'ных фокусов :)

Comment: @avp, дополнил.

Answer (score 5):

Идея решение на С++, написал аналог итератора.

```
FLOAT next(){
static FLOAT prev = NAN;
static bool isFirst = false;
static Seq<float> local = GLOBAL.next();
if (!local)      
    return null; //end result seq
if (isFirst)     //it's first elem in seq so we read it before
    isFirst = false; 
    return prev;    
} 
FLOAT temp = local.next();
if (!temp){ //if we read current seq
    local = GLOBAL.next();
    if (!local)      //we read all seq
        return null; //end result seq
    FLOAT tmp = prev;
    prev = local.next();
    if (!prev){      //if empty seq 
        prev = NAN;
        local = GLOBAL.next(); //go next seq
        return NAN;
    }
    isFirst = true; // we read first elem need save it
    return (prev + tmp)/2;
}
return prev = temp;
}
```

Comment: А что есть `Seq<T>`? В C++ появились генераторы?

Comment: @VladD просто генератор хоть самописный. главное чтобы метод next был, и если всё то null возвращал.

Answer (score 5):

[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) Обычный генератор на [`Enumerator::Lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) и несколько тестиков. Принимает что угодно, что внутри имеет [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html), с элементами, имеющими [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html).

```
def inter_means(sequences)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    last_inserted = nil
    sequences.lazy.each do |seq|
      first = true
      seq.lazy.each do |element|
        if first && last_inserted
          y << (element + last_inserted) / 2.0
          last_inserted = nil
        end
        first = false
        y << element
        last_inserted = element
      end
    end
  end
end
# ---------------- ----------------
# Далее код для тестов

# Поток чисел из stdin (изначально не ленивый!)
stdin_number_stream = Enumerator.new do |y|
  number = ""
  STDIN.each_char.lazy.each do |c|
    if c =~ /\d/
      number += c
    else
      y << number.to_i if number != ""
      number = ""
    end
  end
  # Когда поток закрыли, могло накопиться число
  y << number.to_i if number != ""
end

inputs = [ #       v-вот теперь ленивый
  [[], stdin_stream.lazy, [1]],
  [[*1..5], [*3..6].reverse, [], [-3, -3, -3]],
  [],
  [[], [], []],
  [[], [1, 2, 3], [], [-3, -2, -1], [], []]
]

inputs.each do |input|
  puts "  #{input.inspect}\n=> #{inter_means(input).to_a.inspect}"
end
```

[Пример на `ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/YZgmSN) с печатью `stdin` в `stdout` наглядности ради.

---

```
  [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4, 3], [], [-3, -3, -3]]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 0.0, -3, -3, -3]
  []
=> []
  [[], [], []]
=> []
  [[], [1, 2, 3], [], [-3, -2, -1], [], []]
=> [1, 2, 3, 0.0, -3, -2, -1]
```

Comment: Но это тоже по идее не отличается от алгоритма в вопросе, правильно?

Comment: @VladD да, один в один, просто на другом языке.

Comment: Хороший язык, даже впервые видя код, в принципе многое понятно. А stdin в качестве одной из подпоследовательностей подставить можно?

Comment: @avp если сделать из него ленивую последовательность чисел (примерно таким же способом, хе-хе), то да. Сейчас добавлю пример.

Comment: @avp добавил, тест с ним поставил наверх.

Answer (score 4):

На Python тоже вполне компактненько:

```
def flatten(*lists):
  prev = elt = None
  for lst in lists:
    for elt in lst:
      if prev is not None:
         yield (prev + elt) / 2
         prev = None
      yield elt
    prev = elt

lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4, 3], [-3,  -3, -3]]
print(list(flatten(*lst)))
```

Ровно то же, что и на C# в вопросе.
Как мне кажется, на любом императивном языке решение будет тоже, с точностью до синтаксиса. :)

Comment: А элементы `lst` могут быть разной природы? Например, второй -- функция, а третий -- файл с данными в подходящем формате.

Comment: Над элементами `lst` по условию задачи нужно уметь выполнять арифметические действия `+` и `/`. В python нельзя напрямую складывать файл с функцией и делит это на 2. :)
А вот элементы `lists`могут быть любыми объектами с интерфейсом итератора. И Функциями, и файлами и курсорами бд...

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что здешний форматер плохо подходит для питона и поэтому `prev = elt` под `yield elt` просто немного съехал? / (вот были бы в питоне скобочки, точно писал  бы на нем)

Comment: Нет. Форматирование здесь вполне верное. Устанавливать значение `prev` имеет смысл после окончания внутреннего цикла, иначе `if` будет срабатывать на каждой итерации.

Answer (score 4):

<sup>Решение не претендует на красоту кода, это скорее демонстрация идеи</sup>

[clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure) **Автомат**, также известный как **машина состояний** на *функциях* и *трамплинах*.

**Состояния:**

- `(initial S)`, когда элементы ещё не выдавались и оставшиеся последовательности лежат в `S`, это начальное состояние
- `(processed X C S)`, когда последним выдан `X`, от последовательности остался хвост `C` (может быть пустой), оставшиеся последовательности `S`
- `(junction X S)`, когда последовательность обработали и последним выданным был `X`, оставшиеся последовательности в `S`

```clj
(ns inter-means.core
  "Полный исполняемый пример описываемого решения"
  (require [clojure.test :refer [deftest testing is run-tests]]))

(defmacro =>
  "Макрос, разворачивающий переход автомата в указанное состояние:
 без аргументов завершает автомат, с одним аргументом вызывает
 немедленный переход, с двумя и более возвращает список указанных
 элементов с продолжением из указанного состояния"
  ([]
   ())
  ([state]
   `(fn [] ~state))
  ([element state]
   `(cons ~element (lazy-seq (trampoline ~@state))))
  ([element other & others]
   `(cons ~element (=> ~other ~@others))))

(defn inter-means
  "Функция, принимающая последовательность последовательностей и
 возвращающая ленивую последовательность их конкатенации через
 средние арифметические граничных элементов"
  [input-seqs]
  (letfn [(initial [[[head & tail :as current] & remainder :as inputs]]
            (cond head    (=> head
                              (processed head tail remainder))
                  current (=> (initial remainder))
                  :else   (=>)))
          (processed [last-inserted [head & tail :as current] remainder]
            (cond head  (=> head
                            (processed head tail remainder))
                  :else (=> (junction last-inserted remainder))))
          (junction [last-inserted [[head & tail :as current] & remainder :as inputs]]
            (cond head    (=> (/ (+ last-inserted head) 2)
                              head
                              (processed head tail remainder))
                  current (=> (junction last-inserted remainder))
                  :else   (=>)))]
    (trampoline initial input-seqs)))

(deftest spec
  (is (= (inter-means [[1 2 3 4 5] [6 5 4 3] [] [-3 -3 -3]])
         [1 2 3 4 5 11/2 6 5 4 3 0 -3 -3 -3]))
  (is (= (inter-means [])
         []))
  (is (= (inter-means [[] []])
         [])))

(run-tests)
```

Comment: Смотрел, смотрел (в `*scratch*`), но так и не въехал. Наверное, нет у меня внятных предположений, что же именно означает `a & b` в аргументах функции.

Comment: @avp это [destructuring](https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844). И его синтаксис... упоротый :) `& x` это "и всё остальное в `x`". Разложение на `[a & b :as c]` это "записать в `a` первый элемент, в `b` оставшийся итератор (`rest`), а в `c` оставить исходное значение". В сочетании с вложенностью этот синтаксис начинает потихоньку ломать мозг. Я в первой версии это повыносил в `let`ы изнутри, но код здорово раздуло и я решил его таким образом слегка сжать.

Comment: @avp во что превращается destructuring, можно глянуть формами вроде `(macroexpand '(let [[a & b :as c] s]))`

Comment: Если правильно понял, то это действие в каком-то смысле обратное `(cons ...)`? А `reminder` это еще не обработанные последовательности (о которых я напрочь забыл, ползая по скобочкам)?

Comment: @avp да, можно и так сказать. Да, в `reminder` внешний итератор на оставшиеся последовательности.

Comment: ОК. Кажется въехал. Но не скажу, что реально понимаю, и уж точно написать такое не смогу (впрочем, ничего сложнее простой фигни в .emacs на лиспе не писал).

Answer (score 4):

Ещё один вариант на Python-е:

```
from itertools import chain

def flatten(*lists):
  prev_i = -1
  prev_elt = None
  for i, elt in chain(*map(enumerate, lists)):
    if prev_i != i - 1:
      yield (prev_elt + elt) / 2
    yield elt
    prev_i = i
    prev_elt = elt

lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4, 3], [-3,  -3, -3]]
print(list(flatten(*lst)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 0.0, -3, -3, -3]
```

Идея та же, что и в F#, но получилось несколько компактнее. :)

Здесь:

- `enumerate` делает из последовательности пронумерованную
  последовательность,
- `map` - применяет `enumerate` ко всем переданным
  последовательностям,
- `chain` - сцепляет последовательности.
  В цикле остаётся только проверить, что предыдущий и пекущий индексы не последовательны.

Да, здесь всё "лениво", т. е. элементами `lists` могут быть любые итераторы.

Comment: Симпатично. И что м.б. интересно, размер в строчках обеих питоновских программ совпадает.

Comment: Этот вариант можно подсократить на 2 строчки,за счёт множественных присваиваний: `prev_i, prev_elt = -1, None` в начале функции и `prev_i, prev_elt = i, elt` в конце цикла.

Comment: Ну, вряд ли это добавит коду читаемости, хотя ... дело вкуса.

Answer (score 3):

Решение на F#, в функциональном стиле, без использования его императивных возможностей (for, yield и т.д.):

**UPD.** Убраны лишние обращения к генератору.

**UPD.** Полностью ленивая реализация.

```
let flatten seqs =
    // нумеруем каждый элемент внутренней пос-ти его индексом
    let numbering = Seq.zip (Seq.initInfinite id) in
    // сливаем внутренние посл-ти
    let pairs = (Seq.map numbering >> Seq.concat) seqs in

    let folder (prev_i, prev_elem, _) (cur_i, cur_elem) =
        // если индексы текущего и предыдущего элементов не последовательны
        // значит, это граница, добавляем средний
        let is_bound = cur_i - prev_i <> 1 in
        let with_mean =
            if is_bound then [| (cur_elem + prev_elem) / 2.; cur_elem |]
            else [| cur_elem |] in
        (cur_i, cur_elem, Seq.ofArray with_mean) in

    let take_3rd = function | _, _, x -> x in
        (Seq.scan folder (-1, 0., Seq.empty)
            >> Seq.skip 1
            >> Seq.map take_3rd
            >> Seq.concat) pairs
```

Тесты:

```
[[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]; [6; 5; 4; 3]; []; [-3; -3; -3]]
    |> List.map (List.map float) |> List.map Seq.ofList |> Seq.ofList
    |> flatten
    |> List.ofSeq
    |> printfn "%A"

seq {
    printfn "Generating outer seq";
    yield seq { printfn "Generating inner seq 1"; yield 1.0; };
    yield seq { printfn "Generating inner seq 2"; yield 2.0; };
    yield seq { printfn "Generating inner seq 3"; yield 3.0; }
}
|> flatten
|> List.ofSeq
|> printfn "%A"
```

Результат:

```
[1.0; 2.0; 3.0; 4.0; 5.0; 5.5; 6.0; 5.0; 4.0; 3.0; 0.0; -3.0; -3.0; -3.0]
Generating outer seq
Generating inner seq 1
Generating inner seq 2
Generating inner seq 3
[1.0; 1.5; 2.0; 2.5; 3.0]
```

Comment: А можно короткое объяснение, что этот код делает?

Comment: Придирка: `Seq.isEmpty` скорее всего запустит генератор.

Comment: @VladD да, до первого возращенного элемента. Паттерн-матчинг на seq не работает, если делать активный паттерн-матчинг, то это эквивалентно Seq.isEmpty. Я вообще не очень представляю, как это можно сделать, не запуская генератор :)

Comment: У меня вот что получается: http://pastebin.com/eR41JDiZ. Второй генератор дёргает аж три раза.

Comment: Ну, код на C# же умудряется запускать генераторы лишь по разу. Неужели функциональный язык на функциональной задаче уступит императивному?

Comment: @VladD если бы я изучал его дольше двух недель - точно бы не уступил :D

Comment: @VladD Каждется разобрался, все генераторы теперь дергаются только один раз. Еще и кода меньше стало.

Comment: Ага, так и правда лучше.

Comment: Окей, следующий вопрос — я смотрю на `seqFold`, и оно вроде бы строит новую последовательность при помощи `Seq.append`. Не значит ли это, что произойдёт по одному append'у на каждый элемент исходной последовательности? То есть в памяти окажется структура данных размером с исходную последовательность, хоть бы и ленивая? (Аналогично коду на C# `foreach (var e in seq) result = result.Concat(new[] {e});`) [Я не спрашиваю в соседнем решении на Хаскеле лишь потому, что не знаю его совсем.]

Comment: Например, такой код: http://pastebin.com/aJLkNZeV вылетел по out of memory.

Comment: @VladD вариант 3 :) теперь полностью ленивая реализация, большие последовательности отрабатывает, память почти не используется. По-прежнему без for/yield.

Comment: Точно, перепроверил, память вовсе не расходуется. Идея с расстановкой индексов — отличная! (+1 поставить не могу, т. к. уже поставил.)

Answer (score 3):

А вот еще на Haskell, не настолько втупую как прошлое - но компактнее и (надеюсь) понятнее. На одну строку меньше, ну и сами строки короче.

```hs
flatten :: (Fractional a, Foldable l) => l [a] -> [a]
flatten = foldr concat' []
    where concat' [] y = y
          concat' (x:[]) (y:ys) = x : (x+y)/2 : ys
          concat' (x:xs) y = x : concat' xs y
          concat' x [] = x

main = print ls >> print (flatten ls)
    where ls = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4, 3], [], [-3,  -3, -3]]
```

Тут еще можно было бы `concat'` упростить при помощи функций `init` и `last` - но их совместное применение материализует список, что по условию недопустимо.

Кстати, тот факт что строчка `concat' x [] = x` стоит последней очень важен - без этого входная последовательность окажется полностью материализована при попытке проверить все ее элементы на пустоту :)

Если кто-то решит начать подсчитывать символы - то вот минифицированная версия:

```
f = foldr c []
    where c [] y = y
          c (x:[]) (y:b) = x : (x+y)/2 : b
          c (x:a) y = x : c a y
          c x [] = x
```

Comment: А можно как-нибудь прогнать тесты на ленивость и на нерасход памяти? (Версию на F# пришлось переделывать, чтобы она перестала дёргать генераторы больше, чем один раз, и строить огромные структуры данных в памяти.) Я сам не умею Хаскель, поэтому не знаю, как такое делается.

Comment: @VladD не знаю, отлаживал "внимательным взглядом". В принципе, можно сделать обертку над списком, которая будет выводить сообщения о материализации - `tracelist [] = []` `tracelist x:xs = seq (unsafePerformIO $ print "+") (x : tracelist xs)`...

Comment: А можно сделать список генератором, чтобы он был больше объёма памяти? (А то мне так и не ответили, работает ли паттерн-мэтчинг с генераторами в Хаскеле.)

Comment: @VladD Вот пруф ленивости: http://rextester.com/NANG48806

Comment: @VladD в Хаскеле нет генераторов как отдельной сущности. Благодаря ленивости, любой список ведет себя почти так же, как в другом языке вел бы себя генератор. К примеру, можно сделать бесконечный список.

Comment: @VladD и да, мой код будет работать с бесконечными списками.

Comment: А можно тест того, что в случае бесконечного списка не вылетит по out of memory, а будет спокойной продолжать генерировать результат до бесконечности?

Comment: @VladD да пожалуйста: http://rextester.com/QGTF96024

Comment: @VladD но тут есть тонкость. Если в программе где-то удерживается ссылка на бесконечный список - то его обработка будет кушать память. А вот если по мере обработки списка голова отбрасывается - то сборщик мусора ее приберет и OOM не случится.

Comment: @VladD словом, бесконечные списки в Хаскеле обычно работают - но странных вещей с ними лучше не делать.

Comment: Не, тут его оборвал рантайм. А вы не могли бы запустить на своей машине и посмотреть? Мой первый пример на F# набирал память по 100К/секунду и вылетел через лишь 4 часа.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39115/discussion-between-pavel-mayorov-and-vladd).

Comment: Понятно, что держат в памяти не нельзя, можно, например, пргосто выводить в файл или на консоль

Answer (score 3):

На Haskell-е реализация идеи с нумерацией:

```
flatten [] = []
flatten [y] = y
flatten lists = concat . append_end . map adder . zip xxs $ xs
  where
    xxs@(_:xs) = concat . map (zip [1..]) $ lists
    adder ((n, a), (m, b))
      | n + 1 == m = [(a, b)]
      | otherwise  = [(a, undefined), ((a + b) /2, b)]
    append_end [] = []
    append_end [x] = [map fst x, [snd $ last x]]
    append_end (x:xs) = map fst x : append_end xs
```

1. `flatten [] = []` - Пустой вход - пустой выход.
2. `flatten [y] = y` - Единственный список - его и возвращаем.
3. Общий случай:
4. `xxs@(_:xs) = concat . map (zip [1..]) $ lists` - нумеруем подсписки `map (zip [1..])` и собираем из них общий список `xxs` с хвостом `xs`.
5. `zip xxs $ xs` - Собираем список пар (текущий, следующий).
6. `map adder` - Преобразуем список с вычислением вставляемых элементов.
7. `concat . append_end` - собираем результат с добавлением последнего элемента из последней пары.

Answer (score 2):

[clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure) **Pattern-matching** не является частью языка, так что приходится брать [`core.match`](https://github.com/clojure/core.match):

```
(ns inter-means.match
  (:require [clojure.core.match :refer [match]]))

(defn inter-means
  "Функция, возвращающая ленивую конкатенацию переданной последовательности
  последовательностей через средниые арифметические крайних элементов"
  ([input-seqs]
   (inter-means input-seqs nil false))
  ([input-seqs last-inserted junction?]
   (match input-seqs
      ([] :seq)
      ()

      ([([] :seq) & remainder] :seq)
      (recur remainder last-inserted (-> last-inserted nil? not))

      ([([head & tail] :seq) & remainder] :seq)
      (let [continuation
            (cons head (lazy-seq (inter-means
                                   (cons tail remainder)
                                   head
                                   false)))]
         (if junction?
           (cons (/ (+ head last-inserted) 2) continuation)
           continuation)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну и свёртка, на Haskell:

```
flatten = fst . foldl adder ([], undefined)
  where
    adder x [] = x
    adder ([], _) xs = llist xs
    adder (ys, prev) [x] = (ys ++ [(prev + x)/2, x], x)
    adder (ys, prev) (x:xs) = let (lxs, lx) = llist xs
      in (ys ++ [(prev + x)/2, x] ++ lxs, lx)
    llist [x] = ([x], x)
    llist (x:xs) = let (ys, y) = llist xs in (x:ys, y)
```

1. `flatten = fst . foldl adder ([], undefined)` - результат функции есть первый элемент свёртки слева с применением функции `adder` и начальным значением `([], undefined)`
2. `adder x [] = x` - если второй аргумент - пустой список, возвращаем первый.
3. `adder ([], _) xs = llist xs` - если первый элемент первого аргумента - пустой список, возвращаем кортеж из списка и его последнего элемента.
4. `adder (ys, prev) [x] = (ys ++ [(prev + x)/2, x], x)` - второй аргумент - список из одного элемента `x`, возвращаем кортеж из дополненного списка из первого аргумента и элемента `x`.
5. `adder (ys, prev) (x:xs) = let (lxs, lx) = llist xs
      in (ys ++ [(prev + x)/2, x] ++ lxs, lx)` - общий случай. Возвращаем кортеж из дополненного списка из первого аргумента и последнего элемента `xs`.
6. `llist` - возвращает кортеж из списка и его последнего элемента. Нужна, чтобы не проходить список повторно `last`-ом.

Answer (score 1):

Может, кому понадобится на Java 8:

`// Flattener.java:`

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Flattener {
    private Double lastElement;
    private boolean isFirst;

    @SafeVarargs
    public final Stream<Double> flattenWithInsertedValues(final Stream<Double>... streams) {
        lastElement = null;
        return Stream.of(streams).flatMap(stream -> {
            isFirst = true;
            return stream.flatMap(x -> {
                Stream<Double> part;
                if (isFirst && lastElement != null)
                    part = Stream.of((lastElement + x) / 2.0, x);
                else part = Stream.of(x);
                isFirst = false;
                lastElement = x;
                return part;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Проверка:

`// Main.java:`

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stream<Double> s1 = Stream.of(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0); // 1 кусок
        Stream<Double> s2 = Stream.of(6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0);    // 2 кусок
        Stream<Double> s3 = Stream.empty(); // 3 кусок пустой
        Stream<Double> s4 = Stream.of(-3.0, -3.0, -3.0);    // 4 кусок

        Stream<Double> all = (new Flattener()).flattenWithInsertedValues(s1, s2, s3, s4);
        all.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```