# Код-гольф - Реализация алгоритма выборки комбинаций

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

Приём ответов завершён, всем спасибо за участие!
Можете оставлять свои решения, но победители уже выбраны и пересчёта не будет.

---

Приветствую.

**Задача:** Напишите функцию, которая из произвольного входящего массива выберет все комбинации чисел, сумма которых будет равняться 10.

**Подробнее:**
Диапазон чисел: **0 - 1000** включительно.
Количество чисел во входящем массиве: **1 - 10** включительно.
Уже выбранные числа могут использоваться неоднократно, но комбинации должны быть уникальны.
--- Смена позиций не делает комбинацию уникальной, т. е. `[1,9]` и `[9,1]` не позволяются).
--- При входных данных `[5,5,2,3]` можно сделать `[5,5]`, `[5,2,3]`.
Продолжительность конкурса: **14 дней**.
Обязательный формат метки ответа (для автоматического парсера в таблицу):
`<h2>Язык, КоличествоСимволов</h2>`

**Определение победителя:** Определяется по градации:

1. Реализация, состоящая из наименьшего количества символов.
2. Реализация, получившая больше всего плюсов (общий рейтинг минус голоса против).
3. Реализация, время первой редакции которой раньше.

Необходимо так же давать ссылку на один из онлайн-компиляторов с Вашим **рабочим** кодом.
Тесты приветствуются.
**Настоятельно рекомендуется** давать как конкурсную версию кода (минифицированную и/или с колдунствами), так и наглядное описание этого же кода. Всем интересно не только увидеть языковую магию, но и что-то почерпнуть для себя.

От одного участника допустимо несколько ответов, если они реализованы на разных языках. Но не более одного на язык

---

Все вопросы по деталям и/или разногласиям и/или трактовке условий, прошу обсуждать в комментариях к этому сообщению или в [комнате чата по код-гольфу](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----).

---

**Итоги:**

Стандартные 3 места + 1 за самое большое количество плюсов (общий рейтинг минус голоса против).

**1 место**: [@PavelMayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178779/pavel-mayorov) -   [`Haskell`, **42** символа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582004).
**2 место**: [@ArtemKonovalov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10353/artem-konovalov) - [`Scala`, **69** символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587203).
**3 место**: [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) - [`Perl`, **78** символов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581750).

**Зрительские симпатии**: [@D-side](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/d-side) (`Ruby`, 84) - [19 баллов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581929).

Поздравления всем участникам, вы хорошо сражались.
Особенно страсти накалились в самом конце, когда неожиданно было опубликовано решение обгоняющее лидера на 1 символ.
Но судьба вернула всё обратно.

Хотелось бы отметить необычное для данного соревнования решение от пользователя [@AlexanderGavrikov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/203691/alexander-gavrikov) - **1437** символов!
Это своеобразный рекорд, стоит отметить.

---

**Таблица лидеров:**

```js
execute(581668);
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}

.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}

/* TODO: Fix it */
body {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #212121;
}

#leadership {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem auto;  
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: #fafafa;
}

#leadership td {
  padding: 1rem .5rem !important;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#leadership tr:hover td{
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: #fefefe;
}

#leadership tr:hover td a {
  color: #fff;
}

#leadership th {
  padding: 1.5rem .5rem !important;
  color: #727272;
  text-align: left !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}

#leadership a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #212121;
}

#leadership a:hover {
  color: #03a9f4;
}

#leadership td:nth-of-type(1){
  text-align: center;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

#leadership td:nth-of-type(2){
  
}

#leadership td:nth-of-type(2) img {
  width: 34px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* #leadership th:nth-of-type(1),
#leadership th:nth-of-type(2){
  border-bottom: none;
} */

#leadership th:nth-of-type(5),
#leadership th:nth-of-type(6),
#leadership th:nth-of-type(7),
#leadership td:nth-of-type(5),
#leadership td:nth-of-type(6),
#leadership td:nth-of-type(7) {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/97314479fcd24a2386e1.js"></script>
<div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

**Удачи всем!**

Comment: а ограничения по времени есть? + Что считать разными комбинациями (позиции или значения)

Comment: @pavel, да, 14 дней с момента начала. Позиции не важны, главное чтобы комбинации были уникальны.

Comment: по времени работы...

Comment: @pavel, время работы алгоритма в разумных пределах, но потолка нет.

Comment: где можно посмотреть на ответы?

Comment: @stas0k, как только ответы будут даны, их список можно увидеть тут в качестве ответов или в таблице лидеров вопроса.

Comment: _"Уже выбранные числа могут использоваться неоднократно"_ - из `5,2,3` можно выбрать `5,5`?

Comment: а куда сортировка пропала? вроде ж была

Comment: @Grundy, **что-то** было, пофиксил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, разрешено повторять в разных комбинациях. В текущей - уже выбрано число, больше нельзя.

Comment: Зачем диапазон 0..1000, когда сумма всего лишь 10?

Comment: @alexolut, чтобы фильтровать такие числа, если нужно.

Comment: "Первое место в качестве приятного бонуса получает награду конкурса." - это вы за меня решили, кто награду получает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так вроде награда передаётся принятому ответу. Да и логично это. Или у Вас есть идея получше? Я слушаю.

Comment: @Other награда передаётся принятому ответу только когда инициатор конкурса "пропал". А так - какой выберу, тому и передаётся, моя же награда. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не знал :) Тогда просто положусь на Вашу проницательность.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Haskell, 42 <s>70</s> символа

```
g=nub.filter((10==).sum).subsequences.sort
```

Требует импорта функций `nub`, `sort` и `subsequences` из Data.List

Запуск: `main = print $ g [5,5,2,3]` *http://ideone.com/5jUIsy*

Как работает:

- входной список сортируется (иначе функция `nub`, см. далее, не поймет);
- функция `subsequences` находит все сочетания (без ограничения длины), их 2<sup>m</sup>, где m - длина входного списка;
- при помощи `filter` выбираются те сочетания, которые дают нужную сумму;
- при помощи `nub` выбираются различные сочетания.

PS спасибо участнику Artem Konovalov за то, что опосредованно [подсказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587203/178779) мне не писать велосипед, а заглянуть в стандартную библиотеку языка :)

Comment: Разместите код в онлайн и в рабочем виде, пожалуйста. Со всеми импортами и функциями.

Comment: Интересно, а разве импорты считать в длину не надо ? Ведь так сейчас можно готовую библиотеку для какого нибудь языка найти, которая делает то что нужно ...

Comment: @Mike это системная библиотека. На том же C# юзинги и объявления класса тоже традиционно не учитываются.

Comment: @Mike, встроенное, "из коробки" не считается.

Comment: хаскель в гольфе вне конкуренции, это точно, даже читерский `combination` не спас руби, это потому что `combination` длинно)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр на самом деле, вне конкуренции специальные языки, созданные для гольфа :)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov но это уж будут реализации совсем далекие от реалий, а хаскель и в бою используют

Comment: "(напишет 2) " - что значит напишет два? два варианта ответа?

Comment: @4per ничего не значит. Сначала я другую задачу решал, осталось случайно :)

Comment: А что, импорты не включаются в подсчёт количества символов?

Comment: @NickVolynkin из стандартной библиотеки - нет

Comment: @PavelMayorov жесткая типизация скалы не позволила написать короче(

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov а в Хаскеле типизация тоже жесткая :)

Comment: Ну и наконец награда за первое место )

Answer (score 26):

### Ruby, 84 <s>91</s>

```
->a{(1..a.size).flat_map{|n|a.sort.combination(n).select{|c|c.reduce(:+)==10}.uniq}}
```

Первое решение, которое таки умещается в одну строку при просмотре с сайта!

Это литерал лямбды, который надо вызвать с массивом входных данных. Результатом будет массив из найденных комбинаций.

[**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/uwSkNW)

В Ruby функция получения комбинаций элементов массива реализована прямо в классе `Array`, в стандартной библиотеке. **Ой.**

В остальном, решение максимально прямое и неплохо переводится на естественный язык:

```
(1..a.size)              # Для диапазона от 1 до длины массива А
  .flat_map{ |n|         # ...сконкатенировать для каждого N в нём следующее:
    a.sort               #   Из отсортированного массива А...
     .combination(n)     #   ...взять все комбинации длиной N элементов
     .select{ |c|        #   ...выбрав только те С из них, в которых:
       c.reduce(:+)==10} #     Cвёртка С сложением равна 10.
     .uniq}              #   ...убрав повторения.
```

Поскольку порядок в комбинациях неважен, чтобы не получить дубликатов, массив можно отсортировать. Можно отсортировать и комбинации постфактум, но это медленнее и требует больше символов.

Comment: Победитель определён :D

Comment: Читер :) Но ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: Проверил - на кейсе `[5, 2, 3, 5]` [не работает](http://ideone.com/VOj7JY)!

Comment: @PavelMayorov он выведет баг! ...который легко пофиксить, но нужно. Момент.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр кажется, вы ошиблись xD

Comment: @D-side вот почему я люблю Ruby :D

Answer (score 23):

### SQL SQLite <s>Oracle 11.2</s>, 104 <s>114</s> <s>124 <s>147</s> 176</s>

#### *обнаружен баг (см.комментарии)*

#### Реализация алгоритма выборки комбинации слагаемых для получения заданной суммы из заданного набора значений, с помощью рекурсивных SQL-запросов

- Решение на конкурс

```sql
 WITH t(p,w,s)AS(SELECT'',0,0 UNION SELECT p||i||';',r,i+s FROM t,a WHERE r>w)SELECT p FROM t WHERE s=10;
```

- Подготовка

```sql
-- создаём таблицу с данными
CREATE TABLE a (r INTEGER, i INTEGER); 

-- заполняем
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,5);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (2,5);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (4,3);
```

- Читаемый вариант решения
  *в конкурсном убраны алиасы. вместо `t.r` - `w`, `a.r` - `r`, `a.i` - `i`*

```sql
WITH t (p, r, s) AS
  (SELECT '', 0, 0 -- инициализация кортежа для рекурсии
   UNION
   SELECT 
     p || a.i || ';' , -- сбор строки для вывода
     a.r, -- запоминаем номер строки, чтоб не взять дважды    
     a.i+s -- накопительная сумма
   FROM t, a
   WHERE a.r > t.r -- ограничение - не использовать уже учтенные строки 
  ) 
SELECT p -- вывод комбинаций
FROM t 
WHERE s = 10; --наше конкурсное условие - сумма=10
```

- Выдача

```
P
5;5;
5;2;3;
```

- [Тест (Home - читабельный код, Tab 2 - конкурсный)](http://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-581bf5bed566c3672c3ebde44ef1c8db3eae59aa486b883275)

Comment: Если заменить оракл на другую бд, можно избавиться от `from dual`.

Comment: @ Спасибо, изменил на SQLite

Comment: Код работает неверно. Для последовательности [5, 5, 2, 3, 7, 2] в выводе присутствуют комбинации [5, 2, 3] и [5, 3, 2], которые по правилам считаются одинаковыми.
[Пруф](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-58273c36d9db33f9eac14e5e85c328c511557a957b4c519224)

Comment: @JackApplegame, да уж, такого теста я не делал ): [вариант исправления 146 символов](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-582753e484c9db0502f941cc60be7a4778ae18a7aed5665502)

Answer (score 19):

### perl, 78    <s>81</s> <s>95</s> <s>98</s> <s>109</s> <s>112</s> <s>118</s> <s>121</s> <s>123</s> <s>178</s>

```
use List::Util 'sum';  # В размере не учитывается - библиотека "из коробки"

sub X{for$c(sort@_){@r=map{$_,[@$_,$c]}@r,[]}grep{!$f{"@$_"}++&&10==sum@$_}@r}
```

Тест на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/UL9YWj)

Не сжатый вариант:

```
sub X{
 for $c(sort@_) {             # Перебираем отсортированный входной массив
  @r=map {$_,[@$_,$c]} @r,    # Для каждого элемента в массиве вариантов добавляем
                              # такой же но с добавленным текущим числом
                          []  # Затравка первого цикла - пустой массив
 }
 grep {                       # Выбираем те элементы массива
       !$f{"@$_"}++ &&        # Которые еще не встречались ранее
       10==sum@$_             # И сумма элементов которых равна 10
      } @r
}
```

Старый вариант с рекурсией (95 символов):

```
sub X {                              # Основная функция
  my$n=pop;                          # $n=первый параметр (текущий остаток)
 @_=sort@_;                          # Сортируем входной массив
 my %r;                              # Объявляем хеш результатов
 map {                               # перебираем массив
  my$a=$n-(my$c=pop);                # вытаскиваем очередной элемент массива (в $c)
                                     # и вычисляем текущий остаток минус данный элемент массива
    $r{"$c,$_"}++ for X(@_,$a)       # Кладем в хеш результатов каждый элемент массива,
                                     # который вернет функция перед которым текущий элемент с запятой
  $r{$c}++ if!$a                     # Если разность 0 - то кладем в результаты само число
 } @_;
 keys%r                              # возвращаем массив результатов
}

# Вызов    
@A=(1,3,4,5,3,3,7,2,7,10);           # Тестовый массив
$,="\n";
print X(@A,10);
```

Comment: Позвольте узнать: 1) Что это `$#_+1`? Ясно что итератор, как? 2) Как заполняется `push @r,"$c,$_" for X($a,@_)`? Благодарю.

Comment: @Other 1. параметры функции в perl содержатся в массиве `@_`, количество элементов минус 1 в этом массиве (индекс последнего элемента) это `$#_`. изначально я написал `$#_>=0` но это на 1 символ длиннее `$#_+1`. А вот первый shift внутри цикла берет первый элемент массива и сдвигает массив. 2. предположим у нас $c=5, а функция X для остатка массива вернет массив значений `[5, "3,2", "2,2,1"]` тогда for пробежит по этому массиву и создаст строки "$c,5" (т.е. "5,5"), "5,3,2", "5,2,2,1" собственно эти строки и будут положены в массив @r.

Comment: @Other Кстати, заменил shift на pop, он короче и забирает элемент из конца массива, а не из начала, на суть алгоритма не влияет. И исправил ошибку, `if($a>0)` стало `if($a>=0)`, а то иначе если в конце массива нули, они не обрабатывались

Comment: @Other Кажется я понял, что вас с for смутило. Если вы с perl не сталкивались, то выполнение строки справа налево выглядит конечно непривычно. В других языках эта строка была бы что то вроде `for($_ in X($a,@_)) { push(@r, $c+","+$_) }`

Comment: Исчёрпывающе, благодарю.

Comment: Все, у меня теперь без шансов )

Comment: @Nofate, не печальтесь, у Вас признание зрителей :)

Comment: @Nofate Ну мне вчера 112 казалось последним пределом, оказалось есть что выжимать.

Answer (score 19):

### JavaScript, <s>163</s> <s>148</s>  <s>141</s> <s>129</s> <s>124</s> <s>118</s> <s>109</s> 92

байткод для конкурса :) Совместное творчество с @Mike .

```
f=(n,s,c,r=[],i=0)=>{for(s?0:c[r.join()]=r;i<n.length;)f(n,s-n[i],c,[n[i],...r].sort(),++i)}
```

Пояснения к коду:

```js
var input = prompt('Введите цифры через запятую, к примеру 5,5,2,0,3,4,10,2,56,2,0,8');
input = input ? input.split(',').map(function(v){return parseInt(v);}) : [];

f=(n/*входной массив чисел*/,
   s/*желаемая сумма*/,
   c/*выходные данные*/,
   r=[]/*слагаемые - промежуточная переменная*/,
   i=0/*текущий шаг - промежуточная переменная*/)=>{
  /*запуск рекурсии, которая обойдёт все комбинации чисел в массиве 
   , комбинация на каждом шаге в аргументе r
   , (желаемая_сумма - сумма_комбинации) : в аргументе s*/
  for(
    s?0:c[r.join()]=r;/*если сумма == 0 - записываем слагаемые в выходные данные*/
    i<n.length;/*рекурсия останавливается, когда доходим до последнего элемента*/
  )
  f(n,
    s-n[i]/*вычитаем из суммы текущий элемент массива*/
    ,c
    ,[n[i],...r].sort()/*добавляем в слагаемые текущий элемент массива, сортируем для уникальности*/
    ,++i/*повторяем операцию для следующего элемента массива*/)
}

var output = {};
f(input, 10, output);
alert('Комбинации, дающие 10: ' + Object.keys(output).join('; '));
```

Тест обфускации:

```js
var input = prompt('Введите цифры через запятую, к примеру 5,5,2,0,3,4,10,2,56,2,0,8');
input = input ? input.split(',').map(function(v){return parseInt(v);}) : [];

f=(n,s,c,r=[],i=0)=>{for(s?0:c[r.join()]=r;i<n.length;)f(n,s-n[i],c,[n[i],...r].sort(),++i)}

var output = {};
f(input, 10, output);
alert('Комбинации, дающие 10: ' + Object.keys(output).join('; '));
```

P.S.
Вариант для конурса имеет избыточные аргументы для краткости:
Вторым аргументом необходимо передать желаемую сумму, в нашем случае 10.
Третий аргумент - объект, в который запишется результат, экономия на return надеюсь разрешена)

Comment: 109: `f=(n,s,r=[],c={},i=0)=>{s||(c[r.join(',')]=r);for(;i<n.length;)f(n,s-n[i],[n[i],...r].sort(),c,++i);return c}` при вызове вторым параметром передаем желаемую сумму

Comment: @Mike крутяк, добавь ответ, мне рука не позволит воспользоваться чужими улучшениями :)

Comment: А у меня рука не поднимется писать его как свое, ибо я не знаю на столько JS что бы написать `...r` и даже такое краткое объявление функции для меня совершенно в новинку. Ну а небольшие перестановки сделать, по следам допилки моего perl решения ... это именно небольшие улучшения :)

Comment: @Mike хорошо, будет совместным творчеством)

Answer (score 19):

## R, 111

```r
s<-function(a)unique(Filter(function(x)sum(x)==10,unlist(Map(function(n)combn(a,n,sort,F),c(1:length(a))),F)))
```

Код на [IDE ONE](http://ideone.com/9Gjli3)

Человекопонятный код:

```
solve <- function(a) {
  # собираем вектор с допустимыми длинами комбинаций
  sizes <- c(1:length(a)) 
  # сопоставляем каждой длине комбинации, получаем список списков комбинаций, каждая комбинация пропускается через sort
  combinations <- Map(function(size) combn(a, size, FUN = sort, simplify = FALSE), sizes)
  # делаем список с комбинациями плоским
  combinations <- unlist(combinations, recursive = FALSE)
  # оставляем только комбинации дающие в сумме 10
  combinations <- Filter(function(x) sum(x) == 10, combinations)
  # выкидываем дубликаты
  combinations <- unique(combinations)
  #возвращаем результат
  combinations
}
```

Вызывется на интересующем векторе

```
s(c(2,3,5,5))
```

Comment: Однозначно плюс. Только сжатый и подробный листинги отличаются, можно узнать что творится в конкурсном решении?

Comment: Там то же самое, только без промежуточных переменных

Comment: грубо говоря, `a <- f(g(x))` я расписал как `a <- g(x)`; `a <- f(a)`

Answer (score 18):

### PHP, 114   <s>120 127 130 131 132 143 151 140 142 145 149 163 171 172</s>

По количеству так-же, но выдает меньше предупреждений и работает быстрее.

```
function($a,&$o){for(;2e3-$c++;$d&=$t=[])foreach($a as$k=>$e)1<<$k&$c?:($d+=$t[]=$e)-sort($t)-9?:$o[join($t)]=$t;}
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f8de20b43e35da7dff2e77ef0d37d0c5225e4cb)

```
function($a, &$o){
    for(; 2e3 - $c++; $d &= $t = [])                 // Перебор битовых масок массива 0..1023(2000)
        foreach($a as $k => $e)
            1<<$k&$c                                 // Попадает ли элемент в маску?
                ?: ($d += $t[] = $e) - sort($t) - 9  // sort() == 1,  ($d += $t[] = $e) == $d
                    ?: $o[ join($t) ] = $t;          // join совместно с sort обеспечивают уникальность
}
```

Comment: Боюсь, в гольфе только одна реализация от одного участника. Удалите одну реализацию, пожалуйста.

Comment: Обычное требование для гольфа. Для и для всех, наверное, подобных конкурсов - вариантов можете делать сколько хотите, но на конкурс только один.

Comment: @Other впервые слышу о таком. Была просьба от модераторов "не публикуйте несколько ответов на один вопрос (если нет веских причин)", но в соревнованиях как раз часта ситуация, когда один участник участвует разными решениями на нескольких языках или существенно разными способами (да [я и сам так делал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518338/181100)). Здесь, впрочем, не тот случай.

Comment: @D-side, не спорю - у каждого свои правила. Мне ближе этот стиль. Пока нет официальных правил, которые все приняли, приходится обходится своими. Решение проблемы с глобальными правилами будет скоро обсуждаться мой в чате гольфа.

Comment: @Other, нет таких правил. Можно сколько угодно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, см. условие в вопросе. А список правил создаётся.

Comment: @Other, ну дописал ты - и что с того?

Comment: @Qwertiy, как что? Следовать надо этим правилам значит.

Comment: PHP проигрывает своим долларом перед переменными)

Answer (score 15):

### Python3, 130         <s>131 136 144 147 168 182 216 226</s>

Минифицированный вариант:

```
def r(a,c=[],z=[]):
 a.sort()
 for i,v in enumerate(a):z+=[c+[v]]if v+sum(c)==10*0**(c+[v]in z)else r(a[i+1:],c+[v],z)*0
 return z
```

Пример использования:

```
res = r( [1,4,5,5,2,3,1,4] )
print( res )
```

Минифицированная версия исключительно для гольфа.

---

Не минифицированная версия:

```
def recur( arr, curArr, maxSumm ):
    arr.sort()
    curSumm = sum( curArr ) # текущая набранная сумма, не забываем, что sum([]) == 0
    result = []
    for i in range( len( arr ) ):
        if arr[i] + curSumm == maxSumm: # если в сумме набрали нужное число, то добавляем к результату
            result+=[ curArr + [ arr[i] ] ]
        elif arr[i] + curSumm < maxSumm: # если сумма меньше, то добавляем результат рекурсивного вызова
            result+= recur( arr[i+1:], curArr + [ arr[i] ], maxSumm )
    return result

def unique( arr ): # уникальные значения массива
    unique = []
    [ unique.append(i) for i in arr if i not in unique ]
    return unique
```

Живой пример:
http://ideone.com/ggl9lO

Comment: Да, я этот вопрос там обнаружил поэтому и удалил комент :)

Comment: Сделал жесткую минификацию, но не смог стать короче Perl ^( Ну почему в Python нет нормальной функции unique :)

Comment: Ну в перле без библиотек ее то же нет и ее реализация никак не короче вашей минифицированной :)

Comment: Python обогнал  Вас :)

Comment: О, обогнал мой js'ный вариант :) Кстати, старое количество символов вроде принято зачёркивать?

Comment: вариант с PHP догнал :)

Answer (score 15):

### Javascript ES6, <s>165</s> <s>161</s> <s>150</s> <s>147</s> <s>145</s> <s>134</s> <s>133</s> <s>125</s> <s>123 (неверно)</s> <s>124</s> 118

```
a=>[...Array(2e3)].map((x,q)=>a.filter((x,i)=>q&1<<i).sort()).sort().filter((x,i,a)=>x+""!=a[i-1]&eval(x.join`+`)==10)
```

#### Примечания:

1. Длина массива ограничена 10 числами, поэтому можно использовать перебор по маске.
2. Лямбда-функция не рекурсивная, поэтому её сохранение в переменную не учитывается в числе символов. [Подробнее на codegolf'е.](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6915/32091)
3. Текущая версия функции не создаёт глобальных переменных

#### Проверка:

```js
f=a=>[...Array(2e3)].map((x,q)=>a.filter((x,i)=>q&1<<i).sort()).sort().filter((x,i,a)=>x+""!=a[i-1]&eval(x.join`+`)==10)

console.log(f([5,5,2,3]).join("   "))
console.log(f([5,2,3]).join("   "))
console.log(f([0,10,10,5,0]).join("   "))
console.log(f([0,10,10,5,0,5]).join("   "))
console.log(f([9]).join("   "))
```

Comment: Мне кажется, если я правильно понял задачу - у тебя не проходит условие уникальности.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, а поточнее? Желательно с примером.

Comment: @ReinRaus, `##` и `<h2>` - это одно и то же. Сниппет надо подправить, чтоб зачёркнутое игнорировал.

Comment: Да он вообще Вас игнорирует :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, я его уже исправил :)

Comment: мож я чего не понимаю, но 2;3;5 два раза показывается

Comment: @4per, для какого инпута? В сниппете выводятся результаты 4 тестов, в двух из них по одному разу встречается `2,3,5`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну теперь понятно

Comment: @Qwertiy, всё хорошо, сори. Совсем круто было бы, если бы ты добавил необфусцированную версию кода!

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, я её прям так писал - вроде несложная :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, всё же опишите поэтапно код функции.

Comment: Что-то ошибку выдает при попытке запустить

Comment: @rjhdby, смени IE на что-нибудь нормальное? У меня в хроме всё работает. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: у меня хром. Жму кнопку "выполнить код" и вываливает ошибку.  {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 12
}

Comment: @rjhdby, нужен Chrome 49+. Желательно даже 52+, потому что мне лень разбираться детально по поддержке. Но описанная ошибка может быть только в Chrome 44-. См. раздел arrow functions по ссылке в комментарии выше. И ещё destructing.

Comment: @rjhdby, ну как, получилось запустить?

Comment: @Qwertiy неа. Кровавый энтерпрайз вынуждает использовать "Версия 43.0.2357.132 m". Буду страдать.

Comment: @rjhdby, а FF или Edge? Или дома?))

Comment: @Qwertiy не, кровавый энтерпразй такой кровавый. А дома жена и дети, как-то не до стека :)

Answer (score 11):

### Scala, 69 <s>73, 80</s>

Нечитабельный вариант:

```
def f(a:Seq[Int])=a.indices.flatMap(a.combinations).filter(_.sum==10)
```

пример использования

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
println(f(a))
```

Читабельный вариант:

```
def getSeq(list: List[Int]) =
 list
  //берем индексы т.е. получаем последовательность от 0 до size
  .indices
  //берем всевозможные комбинации длиной index из элементов списка
  .flatMap(index => list.combinations(index))
  //фильтруем списки по сумме элементов == 10
  .filter(s => s.sum == 10)
```

[Демка](http://ideone.com/lzS2zO)

Comment: "Нечитаемый вариант" слабо отличается от читаемого :)

Comment: @ReinRaus немного есть такое)

Answer (score 8):

## C++, <s>174</s> 152

```
using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(auto a){set<m>r;for(int q=2e3,s;--q;){m c;s=10;for(int&x:a)if(q&1<<&x-&a[0])c.insert(x),s-=x;if(!s)r.insert(c);}return r;}
```

Примечания:

- В качестве аргумента следует передавать контейнер, в котором элементы лежат последовательно.

<s>http://ideone.com/4AAo0T</s> http://ideone.com/o1nsmz

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//set<multiset<int>>f(vector<int>a){set<multiset<int>>r;for(int q=2e3,s;--q;){multiset<int>c;s=0;for(auto&x:a)if(q&1<<&x-&a[0])c.insert(x),s+=x;if(s==10)r.insert(c);}return r;} //174
//using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(vector<int>a){set<m>r;for(int q=2e3,s;--q;){m c;s=0;for(auto&x:a)if(q&1<<&x-&a[0])c.insert(x),s+=x;if(s==10)r.insert(c);}return r;} //161
//using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(auto a){set<m>r;for(int q=2e3,s;--q;){m c;s=0;for(auto&x:a)if(q&1<<&x-&a[0])c.insert(x),s+=x;if(s==10)r.insert(c);}return r;} // 155
//using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(auto a){set<m>r;for(int q=2e3,s;--q;){m c;s=0;for(int&x:a)if(q&1<<&x-&a[0])c.insert(x),s+=x;if(s==10)r.insert(c);}return r;} // 154
//using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(auto a){set<m>r;for(int q=2e3,s,i;--q;){m c;s=i=0;for(int&x:a)if(q&1<<i++)c.insert(x),s+=x;if(s==10)r.insert(c);}return r;} // 153
//using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(auto a){set<m>r;for(int q=2e3,s,i;--q;){m c;s=10,i=0;for(int&x:a)if(q&1<<i++)c.insert(x),s-=x;if(!s)r.insert(c);}return r;} // 153
  using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(auto a){set<m>r;for(int q=2e3,s;--q;){m c;s=10;for(int&x:a)if(q&1<<&x-&a[0])c.insert(x),s-=x;if(!s)r.insert(c);}return r;} // 152
//using m=multiset<int>;set<m>f(auto a){set<m>r;m c;for(int q=2e3,s;--q;!s?r.insert(c),0:0){c.clear();s=10;for(int&x:a)if(q&1<<&x-&a[0])c.insert(x),s-=x;}return r;}

int main()
{
    for (auto &r : f((vector<int>){5,5,2,3}))
    {
        for (auto &x : r)
            cout << x << ' ';

        cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Наконец-то :) Правда сжатый код в пояснении таким же и остался, а смысл как раз в пояснении.

Comment: @Other, это не пояснение, а тест. И я его сейчас продолжаю ужимать. Уже 152 получилось :)

Comment: У Вас сейчас 152 символа, но можно на один уменьшить, заменив `multiset` на `list`, а `insert` на `push_back`.

Comment: @alexolut, нельзя. Они кладутся в сет, поэтому любой неупорядоченный контейнер позволит выводить одинаковые наборы с разным порядком чисел. Так что либо `sort`, либо `multiset`. А ещё у меня сейчас 151, а не 152. Или я неверно посчитал?

Comment: Вот [замена](http://ideone.com/qu8Mgn), которую я предлагал и вычисление длины строки. Перепроверьте свои расчеты.

Comment: @alexolut, Вот [форк](http://ideone.com/h4vckS) с другим интпутом - поменял `{5,5,2,3}` на `{5,2,5,3}` - работает неверно. Нужно обеспечить отсортированность чего-нибудь.

Comment: @alexolut, количество символов пересчитал. Действительно на 1 ошибся :(

Comment: Кстати, если уж говорить про символы, то надо и `using namespace std;` со всеми необходимыми `#include` учитывать.

Answer (score 7):

### Java, 1437

Всем добрый день. Не уверен, есть ли однозначность в условии, но насколько я понимаю, если входной массив {2, 3, 5, 5, 0}, то в результате должно быть 4 строки: {2, 3, 5}, {0, 2, 3, 5}, {5, 5}, {0, 5, 5}. Так как массивы {2, 3, 5} и {0, 2, 3, 5} отличаются один {0}, но массивы разные и их сумма равна 10. В некоторых решениях выше при вводе данных {2, 3, 5, 5, 0} ответ будет только из двух массивов {2, 3, 5} и {5, 5}. Написано, Что во входном файле числа от 0 до 1000 включительно, значит нули могут быть.

Написал свое решение на Java. Оно по сравнению с другими очень громоздкое, однако не хранит список массивов в памяти, чтобы удалять дубликаты, а выводит их "на лету", что называется. Плюс учитывает тот случай, который рассмотрел выше.
Большой объем кода еще объясняется написание без использования каких-то стандартных коллекций. Идея в том, чтобы подсчитать количество единиц, двоек, троек и т. д. десяток во входном файле. Зная эту информацию, а также количество нулей, построить ответ.

Рабочий код тут: http://ideone.com/mwV9Uh

Листинг решения:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    int c[] = new int[11];
    void f(int n, int s, int[] cc) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= c[n]; ++i) {
            cc[n] += i;
            s += i * n;
            if (s == 10) {
                for (int z = 0; z <= c[0]; ++z) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < z; ++j) {
                        System.out.print("0 ");
                    }
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; ++j) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < cc[j]; ++k) {
                            System.out.print(j + " ");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
            if (s >= 10) {
                cc[n] -= i;
                return;
            }
            for (int m = n + 1; m <= 10; ++m) {
                f(m, s, cc);
            }
            s -= i * n;
            cc[n] -= i;
        }
   }
   void g() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            int x = scanner.nextInt();
            if (x >= 0 && x <= 10) {
                c[x]++;
            }
            if (x == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        int[] cc = new int[11];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
            f(i, 0, cc);
        }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main x = new Main();
        x.g();
   }
}
```

Вот пример читаемого кода:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

        //количество каждого числа от 0 до 10 во входном файле
        int cnt[] = new int[11];

        //вывод массива на экран
        private void printArray(int[] curCnt) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < curCnt[i]; ++j) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //перебор для вывода вариантов
        private void brute(int number, int curSum, int[] curCnt, int tab) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= cnt[number]; ++i) {
                curCnt[number] += i;
                curSum += i * number;
                if (curSum == 10) {
                    for (int cntZero = 0; cntZero <= cnt[0]; ++cntZero) {
                        for (int i_ = 0; i_ < cntZero; ++i_) {
                            System.out.print("0 ");
                        }
                        printArray(curCnt);
                    }
                }
                if (curSum >= 10) {
                    curCnt[number] -= i;
                    return;
                }
                for (int newNumber = number + 1; newNumber <= 10; ++newNumber) {
                    brute(newNumber, curSum, curCnt, tab + 1);
                }
                curSum -= i * number;
                curCnt[number] -= i;
            }
        }

        private void run() {
            //считывание данных из консоля
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                int x = scanner.nextInt();
                if (x >= 0 && x <= 10) {
                    cnt[x]++;
                }
                if (x == -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            int[] cntCur = new int[11];


      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
            brute(i, 0, cntCur, 0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main solution = new Main();
        solution.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"В большинстве решений выше при вводе данных {2, 3, 5, 5, 0} ответ будет только из двух массивов {2, 3, 5} и {5, 5}."_ - у меня все 4, у ответа, опубликованного до меня было тоже все 4. Но вообще где-то в чате говорилось, что можно нули игнорировать.

Comment: Идея в целом хорошая, я думал про такой подход, но пришёл к выводу,  что он очень плохо ужимается, а это соревнование помечено как гольф. В решении можно было замерять только функцию, а не весь код. Кроме того, не видно никаких усилий по минификации - огромное число необязательных фигурных скобок, а так же отступы и переводы строк (которые можно было оставить, но с пометкой, что они не учитывались в подсчёте символов). Стоит взглянуть на комментарии [тут](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78205/32091).

Comment: Кстати, рад видеть тебя в этом соревновании (что-то не сразу обратил внимание на плашку с автором). Загляни [в соседнее](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/587282/178988) - может на джаве тоже решение придумаешь, а то её до полного комплекта не хватает :)

Comment: *"В большинстве решений выше при вводе данных {2, 3, 5, 5, 0} ответ будет только из двух массивов {2, 3, 5} и {5, 5}."* - стоит перечислить их.

Comment: Например решение на С++, вот сделал форк http://ideone.com/9Zvk

Comment: Корректная ссылка тут http://ideone.com/9Zvkmv

Comment: @Alexander Gavrikov Эм.. Там данные не считываются, в коде захардкожено `f((vector<int>){5,5,2,3})`, писать в stdin то же с ноликом несколько бесполезно ;)

Answer (score 7):

### D, 110

```
import std.stdio;
import std.array;
import std.range;
import std.algorithm;

alias f=e=>e.permutations.map!"a.length.iota.map!(b=>a[0..b+1].array.sort)".join.sort.filter!"a.sum==10".uniq;

void main()
{
    [5, 5, 2, 3].f.writeln;
    [5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 7, 3].f.writeln;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python3, 120

```
def f(a,o,i=0,p=[]):s=sum(p);exec(('o+=([p],[])[p in o];'*(s>9)+'f(a,o,i+1,sorted(p+[a[i]]));i+=1;'*(len(a)-i))*(s<11))
```

**Примечание**

- Результат записывается в параметр функции, т.е. вызываем функцию в виде `f(input_list_of_numbers, output_list_of_combinations)`

[Тест на Ideone](http://ideone.com/IR1KvI)

**Расшифровка кода**

```
def f(a, o, i=0, p=[]):
    s = sum(p);
    if s < 11:
        if s > 9:
            if p not in o:
                o += [p]
        while i < len(a):
            f(a, o, i + 1, sorted(p + [a[i]]))
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scala**

```
(1 to 10).map(i => List.fill(i)((1 to 10).toList).flatten.combinations(i).count(_.sum == 10)).sum
```

Решение, учитывающее варианты типа [ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 2 +2 +2]

В условии говорится "Уже выбранные числа могут использоваться неоднократно" но, например, выйгравший вариант на скале не выводит вариант [ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 2 +2 +2] и ему подобные