# Что не так с модулем?

Tags: jquery, инспекция-кода

Задавала вопрос о том, что лучше использовать: простой код или модули при написании простого скрипта для страницы. На тостере ответили, что модули, но мой модуль ужасен.

О модулях больше всего понравилось [описание тут](http://largescalejs.ru/module-pattern/).

**Вопрос:** что не так с моим модулем?

Пример для простого аккордеона:

```js
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('.accordion').length){
    accordion.init();
  }
});

var accordion = (function(){


  var _openContent = function(el){

    var
        wrap = el.closest('.accordion'),
        item = el.closest('.accordion__item'),
        items = wrap.find('.accordion__item'),
        content = item.find('.accordion__content'),
        contents = wrap.find('.accordion__content'),
        dur = 500;

    if(!item.hasClass('on')){
      items.siblings().removeClass('on');
      item.addClass('on');    

      contents.stop(true,true).slideUp(dur);
      content.stop(true,true).slideDown(dur);
    } else {
      item.removeClass('on');
      content.stop(true,true).slideUp(dur);
    }
  }

  // Инициализация  
  return {
    init: function(){

      $('.accordion__trigger').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var
        $this = $(this);

        _openContent($this);
      });
    }
  }   
})();
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  transition: all .27s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
  color: tomato;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: #727272;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.accordion__item {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
}

.accordion__title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion__trigger {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  background: #9c27b0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.27);  
  padding-left: 3.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion__trigger:before {
  content: '+';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  background: #ff4051;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all .34s ease-in-out;
}

.on .accordion__trigger:before {
  content: '-';
}

.accordion__trigger:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 2rem;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1.25rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1.25rem solid transparent;
  border-left: .5rem solid #ff4051;
}

.accordion__trigger:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #7b1fa2;
}

.accordion__content {
  padding: 1.5rem 3.5rem;
  display: none;
}

.accordion__content span {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #212121;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <ul class="accordion__list">
    <li class="accordion__item">
      <a href="#" class="accordion__trigger">
        <h5 class="accordion__title">Lorem ipsum 1.</h5>
      </a>
      
      <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>
          <span>Content 1. </span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore saepe nulla iure cupiditate libero accusantium deleniti in, quisquam quae quidem.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion__item">
      <a href="#" class="accordion__trigger">
        <h5 class="accordion__title">Lorem ipsum 2.</h5>
      </a>
      
      <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>
          <span>Content 2. </span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore saepe nulla iure cupiditate libero accusantium deleniti in, quisquam quae quidem.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion__item">
      <a href="#" class="accordion__trigger">
        <h5 class="accordion__title">Lorem ipsum 3.</h5>
      </a>
      
      <div class="accordion__content">
        <p>
          <span>Content 3. </span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore saepe nulla iure cupiditate libero accusantium deleniti in, quisquam quae quidem.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Я бы не использовал слова типа "ужасен". Вполне годный код. А вот тостер - это ещё то гетто ИМХО.

Comment: Оффтоп: стили сами придумали или где-то взяли?

Comment: @Other, свои стили, но суть в jq коде) А что на счет, что лучше использовать? Стоит ли для простого аккордеона или таба писать модуль или все это излишне?

Comment: Весьма не нравится, пожалуй, одно - слишком много обращений к DOM. Помещение в модуль аккордеона - нормально, кто-то вообще ратует за то, что код до абсурдного максимально должен быть модульным. Но всё же надо знать меру. Тут можно.

Comment: Стиль мне нравится. Вы не могли бы подсказать интересный стиль для таблицы из сниппета [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581668)? Очень нужно сообществу, а из гетеросексуальных парней дизайнеры плохие (обсуждали в чате тему).

Comment: Можно для своих модулей сделать namespace и добавлять модули в него. Вроде `ElenaUI.accordion`. Посмотрите еще [про плагины к jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), вдруг пригодится.

Comment: @AndrewB, модули изолированы, зачем им `namespace`? Плюс - глубокая вложенность объекта плохо отражается на работоспособности.

Comment: @Other, в коде есть объявление `var accordion = ...`. Если будет создаваться набор модулей для чего-то определенного, считаю, было бы неплохо объединить их в один namespace. Например, к аккордиону добавится еще `tabpanel`, `modaldialog` и что-то еще.

Comment: @AndrewB, для одного модуля - нормально. Где и как хранить набор онных - это другой вопрос. Тогда может и `namespace` поможет.

Comment: @Other, "из гетеросексуальных парней" так посоветовались бы не с не стандартными =))) 
Вообще для таких примеров использую https://www.materialpalette.com/

Comment: Нестандартных нет. Надеюсь. Сайт интересный, но там только цвета подбираются (что, конечно, важно, но это не всё). Да и MD как-то не подходит сюда ИМХО.

Comment: @Other, дизайнер из меня некудышный!

Comment: @Other, http://jsbin.com/wetiso/edit?css,output   =))

Comment: Супер! Мои благодарности Вам летят методами OSI! Очень неплохо, добавлю Вас в авторы таблицы по праву.

Comment: @Other,Спасибо) А для чего вообще делаете таблицу? Посмотреть где-нибудь можно будет?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пару небольших замечаний:

1. Использовать один стиль для кавычек (либо одинарные, либо двойные).
   `"use strict";` у вас в двойных, а остальных местах - одинарные
2. Для `;` тоже выбрать один стиль. Если ставите везде, то у вас пропущена после закрытия функции (*Function Expression*) `var _openContent = function(el){ /* ... */ };` и тут `return { /* ... */ };`
3. Вы используете в модуле `$` - внешнюю библиотеку, её лучше передавать в сам модуль как параметр:

   `var accordion = (function($){ /* ... */ })($);`

Сразу понятно, что для использования вашей библиотеки нужна библиотека `jQuery`. При использовании других зависимых библиотек, их так же можно передавать как параметр в *модуль*.

4. `"use strict";` лучше перенести непосредственно в *модуль*, что бы он распространялся именно на него `var accordion = (function($){ 'use strict'; /* ... */ })($);`
5. Думаю, было бы неплохо, если бы в модуль можно было передавать параметры (`wrap`, `item`, `dur` и т.д.) А значения, которые у вас есть сейчас, оставить по умолчанию. Выглядело бы это как то так:

---

```
// в init передаем объект с параметрами
accordion.init({
  dur: 1000
});
// ...
_openContent($this, setting); // передаем эти параметры в _openContent
// ...
var _openContent = function(el, setting){
  setting = setting || {}; // по умолчанию пустой объект
  var dur = setting.dur || 500; // -> 1000
  var wrapSelector = setting.wrapSelector ||'.accordion';  // -> '.accordion'
```

6. Рекомендация (как и все остальные пункты), но тут уже дело вкуса. Если значение переменной является *jQuery-объектом*, то имя переменной можно начинать с `$` - `var $container = $('.container')`. Тогда в коде сразу понятно (например, по вашему примеру, тут: `contents.stop(true,true)`), что мы работаем в данном месте с *jQuery-объектом*, а не с обычным js-объектом, у которого есть метод `stop`. В процессе написания кода, рефакторинга или поиска ошибок становится ясно, с чем работаем (возможно и не сразу, но я думаю вы поняли о чем я)

Для первых двух пунктов я рекомендую использовать *eslint* (или другие синтаксические анализаторы кода), которые сразу будут подчеркивать (выводить) такие ошибки.

И если ещё не сформировался свой стиль написания кода или когда работаете в команде, удобно использовать единый стиль, например [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) или [StandartJS](http://standardjs.com/index.html) (по которому не нужно ставить точку с запятой). Сам придерживаюсь [Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/es5-deprecated/es5) ([на русском](https://github.com/uprock/javascript)) - очень хорошо написан.