# И станет 3 бесконечностью

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

Посмотрим на классический цикл (с пустым телом), который обычно выполняет 3 итерации:

```
for (int x=0; x<3; ++x);
```

Задача заключается в том, чтобы сделать его бесконечным.

---

### Соревнование завершено, но ответы публиковать можно

Длительность соревнования 2 недели, начало отсчёта после окончания
[Код-гольф - Реализация алгоритма выборки комбинаций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581668/178988)

Опубликовал это соревнование на codegolf'е.

При оформлении ответа рекомендуется язык делать заголовком (`#` в начале строки).

### Оценка

Побеждает ответ с наибольшим рейтингом.
Один участник может  публиковать любое число ответов, если их идея или язык различаются.

Голосующих просьба учесть, что система SO откатит 3 и более минуса, поставленные одному участнику (но не 3 плюса). Больше 3 плюсов одному участнику за день ставить тоже не стоит. Лучше вернитесь завтра и доставьте :)

Решения, нарушающие условия помечаются внеконкурсными с описанием, какое требование они нарушают. Они могут быть по-своему интересны, поэтому удалять их не обязательно.

### Подробные условия

- Можно использовать любой язык в котором поддерживается подобная форма циклов.
- В *чистой* программе на этом языке тип данных должен раскрываться в целочисленный или числовой (если в языке поддерживается типизация), а цикл выполняться 3 раза. Использование пользовательских типов недопустимо.

  ```
  for (int          x=0; x<3; ++x);   // C, C++, C#
  for (var          x=0; x<3; ++x);   // C#, Javascript
  for (auto         x=0; x<3; ++x);   // C, C++
  for (auto signed  x=0; x<3; ++x);   // C, C++
  for (register int x=0; x<3; ++x);   // C, C++
  ```
- В *дополненной* программе цикл должен быть бесконечным, а все ограничения кроме сохранения этого фрагмента кода снимаются.
- Участок с циклом должен быть одинаковым в чистой и дополненных программах.
- `for` должен остаться циклом. Более того, он должен сам стать бесконечным. Просто обернуть его во внешний бесконечный цикл нельзя.
- Тело цикла не должно менять значение переменной. Программа должна работать аналогичным образом с пустым телом цикла.

---

Кстати, есть 3 мои решения (на C#, C++ и Javascript), использующие совершенно разные подходы. Если никто не предложит такие варианты в течение недели с момента начала отсчёта, я их опубликую. А пока только это:

```
oCrfu6vbxewj8k8eMw9TDog83T
```

Первое (на Си++) нашёл @pavel: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587588/178988
Моя версия: http://ideone.com/xgTeCr

Второе (на C#) нашёл @VladD: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587673/178988
Моя версия: http://ideone.com/8bkwoD

Третье (на JS) не написали, публикую: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593174/178988
Фиддл: https://jsfiddle.net/893f6vw8/
Но есть 3 решения с похожей идеей. Подробнее в ответе.

---

### Результаты

- Первое место с 24 голосами занимает [решение](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587547/178988) участника [@soon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176045/soon) на Си/Си++:

  > `#define x x,y`
- Второе место с отставанием всего в 1 голос занимает [решение](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587588/178988) участника [@pavel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182935/pavel) на Си++. Интересно, что это решение было одним из трёх анонсированных.

  > `#define int bool`
- Третье место с 20 голосами получает [решение](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587408/178988) участника [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike) на Перле

  > в котором константа 3 переопределяется значением бесконечнось

---

PS: Напоминаю про [чат](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----)

Comment: С числом 8 было бы *ироничнее* )

Comment: А если язык позволяет написать блок continue для цикла, который формально его телом не является, но выполняется после каждой итерации - в нем можно модифицировать переменную ? :)

Comment: @Mike, в php-ответе я сказал, что [можно](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587303/178988).

Comment: @Nofate, а как же 42?

Comment: Я одного не понимаю `for (int x=0; x<3; ++x)  x--;` - решение же банальное. Получается суть задания - посильнее извратиться?))

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, нельзя изменять тело цикла и сам код цикла. Должно быть две программы: одна нормальная (где цикл выполняет 3 итерации), другая дополненная (где цикл бесконечен), причём изменения не могут затрагивать ни объявление переменной, ни сам код цикла. Ещё обе программы должны работать аналогичным образом при пустом теле цикла.

Comment: @Qwertiy а, понятно. Ясно)

Comment: Интересно, на C/C++  **БЕЗ** `#define` что-то можно сделать? просто с `#define` - уже, как по мне, отличий нет, что именно воткнуть - принцип-то один...

Comment: Где решение на JS?

Comment: @Other, тут. Забыл вчера комментарий добавить.

Comment: Мдя, не то, чтобы ожидал чего-то нового, но хотелось приятно удивится :)

Comment: @Harry, готово: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598528/178988

Answer (score 49, accepted):

По аналогии с @Qwertiy, но работает еще и в Си

```
#define x x,y

int main() 
{
    for (int x=0; x<3; ++x);
    return 0;
}
```

Развернется в

```
int main(void)
{
   for (int x,y=0; x,y<3; ++x,y);
   return 0;
}
```

`y` инициализируется нулем и не меняется в теле цикла, поэтому всегда `<3`

Comment: 10/10, про самый коварный оператор я и забыл

Comment: Остроумное решение )

Comment: Классно!!! Хотя, вроде бы в си не должно быть объявления переменных внутри `for`, но на решение это не влияет.

Comment: @Qwertiy зависит от стандарта, C89 такое не пропустит, да.

Comment: А разве тут не нарушается условие `Участок с циклом должен быть одинаковым в чистой и дополненных программах.`?

Comment: Я не меняю участок с циклом, я лишь добавляю define в самом начале. Второй код - пример программы после обработки препроцессором

Comment: Жалко, что `++x` для неинициализированного `x` - это UB. Но можно использовать `#define x x=0,y` и будет ОК.

Answer (score 35):

## C++

```
int main()
{
    #define int bool
    for (int x=0; x<3; ++x);

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/VwMh2z

bool при всегда 1 или 0, при сравнении с 3 это всегда правда), true++ == true.

Comment: Поздравляю с нахождением одного из трёх анонсированных решений. Вообще-то я ожидал, что решение на шарпе найдут раньше, чем это :)

Comment: Инкремент `bool` [вне закона](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp14.expr).

Comment: @alexolut ну это с++14 вроде бы. До этого было законно.

Comment: @pavel тогда Вам [сюда](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3826/176217) :) Заодно обратите внимание на версию *C++* по Вашей ссылке на `ideone`.

Answer (score 34):

## Java

Итак, чистейшее, дистиллированное зло, хуже не бывает. Хотите насолить тимлиду и вылететь с работы при следующем code review — спросите меня как! Interning + reflection = <3!

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Golf
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Field value = Integer.class.getDeclaredField("value");      
        value.setAccessible(true);
        Integer victim = 0;
        value.setInt(victim, -2);

        for (Integer x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/3Q0Kzc

---

Что здесь происходит? Дело в том, что в Java небольшие целые константы [интернируются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417843/10105): их значения записываются в общий кэш. При помощи рефлексии можно добраться до этого самого закешированного значения, и подменить его!

В примере кода константа 0 подменяется на -2. Не понимаю, почему, но при этом значения в цикле осциллируют между -2 и -1, цикл становится бесконечным.

---

Вариант

```
Integer victim = 3;
value.setInt(victim, -1);
```

тоже загоняет программу в бесконечный цикл (http://ideone.com/WD3qw7), значения меняются как 0, 1, 2, -1, 0, 1, 2, -1, ...

---

Наверное, самое чистое решение (если вообще можно назвать этот код хоть в каком-то смысле чистым) — подменить 3 на `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

```
Integer victim = 3;
value.setInt(victim, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Тогда при сравнении нужное неравенство не сможет выполниться никогда: http://ideone.com/VxIVT7

Comment: http://ideone.com/3LJ5md - модифицированный вариант, который я понимаю :)

Comment: Понял, как оно работает: 0 упаковывается в -2; инкремент превращает -2 в -1; следующий -1 должен превратить в 0, но там ведь упаковка, а 0 снова упаковывается в -2. Вот всё и зациклилось - круто!

Comment: Хм... Я уже знаю как заставить разработчиков основной программы биться об стенку при использовании моей библиотеки)

Comment: @pavel: Если ещё добавить генератор случайных чисел, чтобы проявлялось пореже, или включать проблему на небольшой промежуток времени, будет полный ад. Я ж говорю, абсолютнейшее зло!

Answer (score 28):

**Perl**, Если 3 должно быть бесконечностью - так пусть ей и будет !

Перегрузим метод определения констант таким образом, что бы константа "3" считалась бесконечностью. Любые другие константы пусть означают сами себя.

```
use overload;
BEGIN {
 overload::constant ( integer => sub {
  return inf if($_[1]==3);
  $_[1];
 } );
}

for ($x=0; $x<3; ++$x);
```

[Тест на ideone](http://ideone.com/JBbmbp) (введено искусственное ограничение внутри цикла, что бы сайт не вис)

Comment: Святые угодники, лего отдыхает :)

Answer (score 22):

## C89 и выше

[ideone](http://ideone.com/okyzul)

```
#define for(unused) for(;;)

int main() {
  int x;
  for (x = 0; x < 3; ++x);
}
```

## C99 и выше

[ideone](http://ideone.com/rGqfjw)

```
#define for(...) for(;;)

int main(void) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x);
}
```

Первое решение (C89) работает практически везде с циклом из задания, второе (C99) работает на чуть меньшем кол-ве реализаций, но зато делает бесконечным абсолютно любой for.

Comment: Хм.. Предполагалось, что инкремент будет происходить. Но в целом под условие подходит.

Comment: @Qwertiy ещё можно использовать не variadic macro а обычный с одним параметром, но тогда сломается если использовать внутри скобок запятую.

Answer (score 19):

## C#

Подменяем структуру данных, используя `default`:

```
using System;

// если убрать эту структуру, цикл станет конечным
struct Int32
{
    public static implicit operator Int32(int i) => new Int32();
    public static implicit operator int(Int32 x) => 0;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var x = default(Int32); x < 3; ++x)
            Console.WriteLine("iteration");
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/2evCtl

---

Идея в том, чтобы подменить структуру данных. Создать свою структуру с именем `int` невозможно, но `int` — всего лишь алиас к `System.Int32`, зато возможно создать структуру с именем `Int32` во вложенном пространстве имён `System`.

Если такая структура данных определена во внутреннем пространстве имён, она будет использоваться вместо глобального `System.Int32`.

---

Старый вариант:

```
namespace Golf
{
    // если убрать это пространство имён с содержимым, цикл станет конечным
    namespace System
    {
        struct Int32
        {
            static public bool operator < (Int32 x, int y) { return true; }
            static public bool operator > (Int32 x, int y) { return false; }
            static public Int32 operator ++ (Int32 z) { return z; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (var x = default(System.Int32); x < 3; ++x)
                global::System.Console.WriteLine("итерация");
        }
    }
}
```

Проверка: [чистый код](http://ideone.com/sgkRGt), [дополненный код](http://ideone.com/j5fPwP).

---

Идея переносится на C++, хотя реализация не портабельна, т. к. `#define` ключевого слова `int` стандартом не разрешается:

```
#include <iostream>

struct INT
{
    INT(int i) { }
    bool operator < (int i) { return true; }
    INT operator++(int dummy) { return *this; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// если это убрать, цикл станет конечным
#define int INT
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        std::cout << "iteration" << std::endl;
}
```

Работает под MSVC 2015, с другими компиляторами может и не работать.

Comment: http://ideone.com/zaSx9I - альтернативный способ присобачить вывод на консоль к этому решению :)

Comment: В `g++` тоже работает такое.

Comment: на С++ можно короче - `#define int bool` и всё.

Comment: @pavel: Остроумно. Напишете отдельным решением?

Comment: А как же требование `Использование пользовательских типов недопустимо`?

Comment: @alexolut: Это ведь требование только на «чистый» вариант программы.

Comment: @VladD вот оно что. А зачем вообще это условие?

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, с пользовательскими типами было бы наверное слишком просто. Там, если заменить `int` на пользовательский тип, и просто в конструкторе передавать ему флаг, что перегруженный постинкремент должен ничего не делать.

Comment: Наверное проще было бы вставить слово `встроенный` во фразу `раскрываться в целочисленный`. Хотя когда я читал условие, то подразумевал это по умолчанию. Поэтому и возникло недопонимание про пользовательские типы.

Answer (score 18):

PowerShell:

```
class AlwaysZeroAttribute : System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationAttribute {
    [object] Transform([System.Management.Automation.EngineIntrinsics] $engineIntrinsics, [object] $inputData) { return 0 }
}
[AlwaysZero()]$x=0

for($x = 0; $x -lt 3; ++$x) { }
```

Или

```
Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable x -Mode Write -Action {([ref]$x).Value=0}

for($x = 0; $x -lt 3; ++$x) { }
```

Comment: Ничего себе! И так можно с любым типом?

Comment: @VladD Что Вы имеете в виду под *так*?

Comment: Ну, сделать аналог AlwaysZeroAttribute.

Comment: @VladD Если я Вас правильно понял, то с любым. Какое значение метод `Transform` вернёт, такое и будет сохранено в переменной или передано в последующий атрибут трансформации, если текущий атрибут не последний.

Comment: Круто, не знал, спасибо!

Answer (score 16):

## C++, но не C

http://ideone.com/2m4FCy

```
int main()
{
    int y;
    #define x x=y

    for (int x=0; x<3; ++x);

    return 0;
}
```

PS: Этот ответ придуман после создания соревнования, поэтому публикуется без задержки. На анонсированный выше ответ на плюсах он совсем не похож.

Answer (score 16):

## C#

Ещё одна идея состоит в том, что ключевое слово `var` — контекстное, а значит, его можно переопределить. Поехали!

```
// если убрать эту структуру, цикл завершается
struct var
{
    public static implicit operator var(int i) => new var();
    public static implicit operator int(var x) => 0;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
            Console.WriteLine("iteration");
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/L6H7b7

Comment: Поздравляю с нахождением [ещё одного анонсированного решения](http://ideone.com/8bkwoD)!

Comment: а что? так можно было? :-D

Comment: @Grundy, а почему нет?

Comment: @Grundy: Так можно только потому, что в C# `var` — контекстное ключевое слово. С `int` так не работает.

Answer (score 15):

**JavaScript:**

Воспользуемся возможностью переписать сеттер:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  // Обычный тест
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
    get: _ => window._value,
    set: n => window._value = n
  }) && (window._value = 0);

  for (x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    console.info(x);
}());
```

```js
// Бесконечность — не предел! © Базз Лайтер

// ВНИМАНИЕ: Запуск этого сниппета убьёт эту вкладку или даже браузер
// Запускать с диспетчером вкладок на руках
Object.defineProperty(window, 'x', {
  get: _ => this._value,
  set: n => this._value = 0
}) && (window._value = 0);

for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
  console.info(x);
```

Comment: А что такое диспетчер вкладок?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Shift+Esc, если пользуешься хромом.

Answer (score 15):

*Что в инет попало - то там навсегда xD*

PHP [declare + тики](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.declare.php)

```
<?php

declare(ticks=1);

// Функция, исполняемая при каждом тике
function tick_handler()
{
    global $x;
    $x = 0;
}

register_tick_function('tick_handler');

for ($x=0; $x<3; ++$x);
```

Тест http://ideone.com/QWFDQ3

*Изначальный автор ответа предпочел скрыться*

Comment: Если внутрь цикла внести какую либо полезную нагрузку, то tick_handler будет выполняться более одного раза на одну итерацию цикла и это может привести к неопределенному поведению. Стоит заменить --$x на обычное $x=0;

Comment: @rjhdby и правда

Answer (score 10):

Подключаю тяжелую артиллерию:

```
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location);
        var type = assembly.MainModule.GetType(typeof(Program).FullName);
        var il = type.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Test)).Body.GetILProcessor();

        foreach (var instr in il.Body.Instructions.ToList())
        {
            switch (instr.OpCode.Code)
            {
                case Code.Brtrue:
                    instr.OpCode = OpCodes.Br;
                    il.InsertBefore(instr, il.Create(OpCodes.Pop));
                    break;
                case Code.Brtrue_S:
                    instr.OpCode = OpCodes.Br_S;
                    il.InsertBefore(instr, il.Create(OpCodes.Pop));
                    break;
                case Code.Brfalse:
                case Code.Brfalse_S:
                    instr.OpCode = OpCodes.Pop;
                    break;
            }
        }

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        assembly.Write(ms);
        var assembly2 = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
        var type2 = assembly2.GetType(typeof(Program).FullName);
        type2.GetMethod(nameof(Test)).Invoke(null, new object[0]);
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"i = {i}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Круто, хотя и не могу понять, насколько это соответствует условию. Свой собственный класс переписать не сможешь, чтобы уж точно соответствовало?

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле?

Comment: В смысле вместо `type2.GetMethod(nameof(Test)).Invoke(null, new object[0]);` сделать вызов просто `Test()` или `(new Program()).Test()`. Потому что чистая версия ведь явно не вызывает метод таким способом.

Comment: @Qwertiy и что? Код снаружи цикла менять-то можно...

Comment: Вроде бы дополнять, а не менять? Это либо дыра в условии, либо решение ему не соответствует. Но оно всё равно классное. Предполагалось, что вызов метода в таком случае тоже менять нельзя.

Comment: @Qwertiy подумаю что тут можно сделать. Мысль есть, нет времени

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Например, сделать нестатическую функцию, и присвоить указателю ссылку на новосозданный объект?

Comment: @VladD MarshallByRefObject и отдельный AppDomain. Только надо еще найти как создавать объект в другом домене через new. Remoting так умел делать...

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Наверное так: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: @VladD нее, там был способ именно что конструктор подменить

Comment: @VladD https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hcd5d6y7(v=vs.110).aspx - надо бы раскопать как это шаманство работает :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Это: http://stackoverflow.com/a/194671/276994?

Answer (score 9):

## Perl

Играем с переменными.

Свеженькое, по результатам чата. Вообще без `typeglob`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Variable::Magic qw/wizard cast/;

# тут одна переменная $x:
cast our $x, wizard( set => sub {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    $$ref = 0;
} );

# а тут - другая :-)
for ( local $x = 0; $x < 3; ++$x ) {
    say "[x = $x]";
}
```

---

А здесь мы явно создаём алиас для записи в глобальной таблице имён и вешаем визард на него. Сама же переменная, к которой прицеплен алиас (и на которую указывает запись), формально объявляется позже, в цикле. В принципе того же самого можно было бы добиться и с `tie`, но так веселей :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Variable::Magic qw/wizard cast/;
use Data::Alias;

alias my $foo = *x{SCALAR};

cast $$foo, wizard( set => sub {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    $$ref = 0;
} );

for( our $x = 0; $x < 3; ++$x ) {
    say "[x = $x]";
}
```

---

То же самое, но без `Data::Alias`:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Variable::Magic qw/wizard cast/;

my $foo = \${*x{SCALAR}};

cast $$foo, wizard( set => sub {
    my ($ref) = @_;
    $$ref = 0;
} );

for ( our $x = 0; $x < 3; ++$x ) {
    say "[x = $x]";
}
```

Ideone, к сожалению, ничего не знает про `Data::Alias` и `Variable::Magic`.

Comment: Инициализация переменной происходит не в цикле, как понимаю.

Comment: А, сейчас подумаю.

Comment: @edem, инициализация или объявление? Объявление может быть вне цикла, но если оно обязательно, то оно обязано сохраниться в дополненном коде. Если переменные можно не объявлять совсем, то объявление до цикла с какими-то выкрутасами - это нормально и ничего дополнительного не требует.

Comment: А ссылку на online ide можно?

Comment: Эм.. А вот тело цикла изменять нельзя.

Comment: Собсно, поправил :) Ideone не знает про модуль `Variable::magic`, так что ссылка туда смысла не имеет.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда хотелось бы уточнений по поводу инициализации/объявления.

Comment: @PinkTux, пошли в [гольфочат](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----)

Answer (score 9):

### Javascript

Вариант с сеттером и с freeze уже был.
Посему представлю вариант с Proxy - хоть это и геттер, но прокси по-своему интересен:

```
var p = new Proxy({},{
    get: function(){return 0;},
    has:  function(){return true;}
});

with(p) {
  for(x=0; x < 3; ++x);
}
```

О прокси можно [узнать тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) . Понравится программистам языков с магическими методами, вроде `__get` или `__set` в PHP

Answer (score 8):

## D

Чистая программа похожа на вариант с C/C++

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    for(int x=0; x<3; ++x) {
        writeln(x);
    }
}
```

Язык D при помощи [строковых миксинов](https://dlang.org/mixin.html) позволяет компилировать любое выражение, результатом которого является строка, как будто содержимое строки было напрямую вставлено в исходный код.

Оборачиваем цикл в строку (вместо кавычек используются ограничители q{}, которые удобны для строк содержащих код, но можно использовать и обычные кавычки), функцией из стандартной библиотеки заменяем "++" на пустоту и микшируем результат в тело функции main. Переменная цикла больше не увеличивается и всегда равна нулю, цикл становится бесконечным:

```cc
import std.stdio;
import std.string;

void main() {
    mixin(q{
        for(int x=0; x<3; ++x) {
            writeln(x);
        }
    }.replace("++", ""));
}
```

Comment: Редкий язык, кстати :)

Comment: Смотря с чем сравнивать :)

Comment: Интересный язык, жаль что, видимо, не взлетит.

Comment: В целом он взлетел. Летит правда низковато, но летит. :D

Comment: В целом и `Dart` взлетел. Пропыхтел пару сотен метров над полем и рухнул.

Comment: D летит уже несколько лет, и медленно набирает высоту. Да и Dart, по-моему, отнюдь не рухнул.

Answer (score 7):

### Javascript

Нагло спер идею из чата :-)

Начальный вариант:

```js
for (var x = 0; x < 3..valueOf(); ++x);
```

Бесконечный

```js
var vof = Number.prototype.valueOf;

Number.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  if (this.toString() == 3) {
    return Infinity;
  }
  return vof.call(this);
}

for (var x = 0; x < 3..valueOf(); ++x);
```

Comment: о_О Не видел в чате такой идеи.

Comment: @Qwertiy, там Other, грозился прототип пропатчить :-) Кстати, не уверен на счет возможности использовать в таком виде, не противоречит ли это правилу - не менять сам цикл.

Answer (score 7):

### Javascript

И еще одно решение, нагло подслушанное в чате

Начальный код:

```
for (x = 0; x < 3; ++x);
```

Бесконечный:

```js
var o = {
  x: 0
}
Object.freeze(o);
with(o) {
  for (x = 0; x < 3; ++x);
}
```

Comment: Ну да, почти оно, но отличается :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ты делал с defineProperty как у Other?

Comment: Я делал с property, но без define)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, аааа, похоже понял как :-)

Answer (score 7):

## Groovy

Groovy, в отличие от Java, позволяет полностью контролировать синтаксическое дерево (AST) единицы компиляции. Этим и воспользуемся.

---

Чистая программа:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++);
```

или для наглядности

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    println(x)
}
```

---

Начинаем колдовать.

Добавим в скрипт явное имя пакета и пометим его своей аннотацией `@LoopMagic`:

```
@LoopMagic
package foo

for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++);
```

Аннотация должна быть к чему-то привязана, а прицепить ее непосредственно к циклу не получится, поэтому нужен пакет. Теперь опишем саму аннотацию в отдельном файле (почему - ниже):

```
@Target([ElementType.PACKAGE])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(classes = [ LoopMagicTransformation ])
public @interface LoopMagic {}
```

Мета-аннотация `@GroovyASTTransformationClass` заставляет компилятор применять к ее носителям AST-трансформации, указанные в массиве `classes`. Теперь остается реализовать сам класс трансформации `LoopMagicTransformation`. Можно сделать это ниже в этом же файле:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)  // 1
class LoopMagicTransformation implements ASTTransformation {
    def void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
        def ast = ([] << sourceUnit.AST.methods*.code << sourceUnit.AST.classes*.methods*.code << sourceUnit.AST.statementBlock).flatten()  // 2
        ast.each { node ->
            node.visit(new CodeVisitorSupport() {  // 3
                @Override
                void visitForLoop(ForStatement forLoop) {
                    super.visitForLoop(forLoop)
                    if (forLoop.collectionExpression instanceof ClosureListExpression) {
                        (forLoop.collectionExpression as ClosureListExpression).expressions[1] = new BooleanExpression(new ConstantExpression(true))  // 4
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Разберем все по-порядку.

1. Мета-аннотация `@GroovyASTTransformation` задает фазу в которой будет происходить трансформация. А нашем случае это фаза семантического анализа. Это самый ранний этап, когда код уже разобран в дерево. Механизм AST-трансформаций вызовет метод `visit` для каждого владельца аннотации `@MagicLoop`. Как мы помним, согласно нашему определению это может быть только пакет. Сам пакет нам совершенно не интересен, но через параметр `sourceUnit` мы можем получить доступ ко всей единице компиляции - скрипту.
2. Скрипт из-за своей природы имеет три AST корня - для задекларированных классов, для методов, не принадлежащих явным образом классам, и для самого тела скрипта. Так что сольем все statement-ы верхнего уровня в общий список `ast` (оператор `*.` работает как `map` - вызывает метод на каждом элементе коллеции и возвращает новую коллекцию из результатов).
3. На получившийся лес statement-ов натравим традицонно применяющийся для AST деревьев паттерн Visitor. Groovy нам помогает, предоставляя абстрактный класс `CodeVisitorSupport`, который берет на себя обход дочерних веток. Так что остается только переопределить метод `visitForLoop(), который будет вызван для найденных for-циклов.
4. Убеждаемся, что это именно for, а не for-each цикл, и подменяем условие продолжения на константу `true`. Теперь любой цикл, объявленный в классе, методе без класса или самом теле скрипта будет крутиться вечно.

Аннотация и трансформация должны находиться в отдельном файле и собираться раньше скрипта, т.к. к тому моменту, когда компилятор будет заниматься компиляцией скрипта, наши вспомогательные классы должны быть уже собраны. По этой причине я не привожу действующий пример на ideone.

Answer (score 6):

## C++

Специально для @Harry вариант без define.
Хотя он и почти не отличается от [варианта](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587588/178988) с define.

http://ideone.com/InWt0t

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef bool size_t;

    for (size_t x=0; x<8; ++x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эээ... Но ведь исходный-то цикл был с `int`'ом! `for (int x=0; x<3; ++x);`

Comment: @Harry, _"В чистой программе на этом языке тип данных должен раскрываться в целочисленный или числовой"_ - size_t подходит. И цикл вполне естественный.

Comment: Блин, вечно я до конца не дочитываю :)

Comment: @Harry, та же фигня)))

Answer (score 4):

**Исправлено**

## C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#define for(x) [](){std::string i("x"); while(1);}();

int main() {
  for(int i=0; i<3; ++i);
  return 0;
}
```

На [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/9szJlA)

Включите, плс, в конкурс)

Comment: Эээ, ну у вас же модифицирован цикл по сравнению с вариантом из трёх итераций.

Comment: Т.е. только тело цикла можно переписывать?

Comment: Ну тогда просто так for (int x=0; x<3; ++x) --x; Или я не пойму фишки конкурса ((

Comment: А в теле нельзя менять переменную цикла. В этом и смысл! Посмотрите на другие ответы, они меняют код _вокруг_ цикла!

Comment: Код изменил, прошу внести в конкурс! :-)

Comment: Да, вроде теперь подходит. Наверное. Похоже на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587304/178988

Comment: Точно. Там тоже for заменяют.

Answer (score 4):

## BASH

Точно работает в `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`

```
#!/bin/bash
set +e
declare -rx i=0
for (( i=0; i<3; i++ ))
do
    echo $i
done
```

Вывод:

```
bash-3.2$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
./test.sh: line 4: i: readonly variable
0
```

Comment: Ни в `sh`, ни в `bash` этот код не работает. С `sh` понятно, а в `bash` переменная `x` объявляется как readonly - почему оно должно работать?

Comment: @PinkTux у меня работает. Оно конечно при каждой итерации будет ругаться, но цикл не прервется

Comment: Может оно от каких-то внешних факторов зависит, типа окружения или версии баша? У меня строго падает на первой же итерации. Да и удивительно что где-то вообще работает. А там точно баш?

Comment: @PinkTux GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15). Специально окружение не настраивал, работает AS IS. Но вы правы, лучше вынести версию в пост

Comment: У меня `GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release`

Comment: @PinkTux немного поправил скрипт, попробуйте

Comment: Не, не хочет работать :(

Comment: У меня в минте не работает: `./inf-test: строка 4: i: доступная только на чтение переменная`. GNU bash, версия 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript

Всё-таки публикую это решение, хотя не совсем уверен, насколько оно отличается от имеющихся.

```
with({get x() {return 0}, set x(val){}})
  for(var x=0; x<3; ++x)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/893f6vw8/

```js
var i=0;

with({get x() {return 0}, set x(val){}})
  for(var x=0; x<3; ++x)
    if(document.write(x+' '), ++i>15)
      break;
```

Разница с [решением @Other](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587309/178988) в том, что моё представляет более чистую чистую версию, а также позволяет объявить переменную в for.

Разница с [решением @ГончаровАлександр](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587939/178988) в отсутствии Proxy.

Ещё из похожего есть [решение @Grundy](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587833/178988), но я бы сказал, что оно принципиально отличается, хотя и использует ту же идею с неизменяемым свойством.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP

Вариант 2. Так как тоже можно формально объявить не соответствующим условиям, то небольшой дисклаймер.

PHP - язык с динамической типизацией. И не объявленная переменная `$x==null==0==false==""`. Код `echo (int) $x;` напечатает `0`.
Следовательно, с точки зрения логики работы, эти два цикла одинаковы. Т.е. они оба выполнятся ровно три раза. Первый вариант при этом один раз, в начале, ругнется, но это ни на что не повлияет:

```
for(;$X<3;$X++);
for($x=0;$x<3;$x++);
```

Собственно код:

```
<?php
class Foo{};
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr){
    global $x;
    $x = new Foo();
    return true;
});
for(;$x<3;++$x);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/KWpjsf)

> #### Вне конкурса, поскольку нарушены требования
>
> - Участок с циклом должен быть одинаковым в чистой и дополненных программах.
> - Программа должна работать аналогичным образом с пустым телом цикла.

Вариант 1.

Можно двояко истолковать в плане соответствия правилам конкурса. Если до вечера решите, что не соответствует, то удалю.

```
<?php
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr){
    global $x;
    $x=0;
    return true;
});

for($x=0;$x<3;$x++) echo 1/0;
```

Comment: Думаю, удалять не надо, решение всё-таки интересное. Но правилам оно не соответствует. Возможно, можно что-то изменить, чтобы решение под правила подходило.

Comment: Да, второй лучше соответствует.

Answer (score 2):

## C#

```
    static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        InfLoop.Test();
    }
}

public class InfLoop
{
    public class var
    {
        public var(int i){val = i;}
        public int val;
        public static var InfDo(var v)
        {
             return  v.val < -1 ? v=v+1 :--v ;
        }
        public static implicit operator int (var a)
        {
            return a.val;
        }
        public static implicit operator var (int i)
        {
            return new var(i);
        }

        public static var operator ++(var v)
        {
            return InfDo(v);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < 3; ++x)
        {
            Console.Write("Inf");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: В этом решении for не становится бесконечным, вместо етого внутри него появляется бесконечный цикл... А в целом похоже на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587673/178988.

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде так становится бесконечным именно for?)

Comment: Имелось в виду "количество итераций цикла for становится бесконечным", а не время его исполнения.

Comment: @Qwertiy так я же поправил код, теперь кол-во итераций бесконечно! или нет?

Comment: Ну, почти да. Теперь переменная [уменьшается](//ideone.com/hsttpW) и в момент переполнения что-то произойдёт - либо исключение о переполнении, либо получится максимальный int, который, очевидно, больше 3.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да мой косяк, поправил!;)

Comment: Кручу-верчу, запутать хочу :)

Answer (score 1):

> #### Вне конкурса, поскольку нарушены требования
>
> - `for` должен остаться циклом. Более того, он должен сам стать бесконечным. Просто обернуть его во внешний бесконечный цикл нельзя.
> - Тело цикла не должно менять значение переменной. Программа должна работать аналогичным образом с пустым телом цикла.

## C#

Не уверен, что абсолютно подходит под условия, но идея с переопределением операторов и т.п. исчерпала себя, а на 100% под условия, кажется, подходит только она.

Чистый вариант:

```
using System;
 
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        l:
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            #if (infinity) 
                goto l;
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Грязный:

```
#define infinity
using System;
 
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        l:
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            #if (infinity) 
                goto l;
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/4mQYWa

Comment: Кажется мне что тут нарушение правила "for должен остаться циклом. Более того, он должен сам стать бесконечным. Просто обернуть его во внешний бесконечный цикл нельзя.". Тут же цикл - это метки.

Comment: @Other согласен, насчёт этого пункта у меня тоже сомнения. Однако "формально" внешнего цикла нет и for остался самим собой. Тут уж как рассудят.

Comment: Эм, нет, прямое нарушение. Иначе можно написать `while(1){for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++);}` и заявить что всё ОК, ведь `for` неизменен. Лично мне способ показался интересным, но нарушение...

Comment: @Other, while(1){} является циклом, оператор перехода - нет.

Comment: Не пытаюсь слепо стоять на своем, однако послушаем ещё мнения, ок?

Comment: Думаю циклом является всё, что... циклично. В любом случае, решать будет автор.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Вне конкурса, поскольку нарушено требование
>
> - Участок с циклом должен быть одинаковым в чистой и дополненных программах.

## Perl

Пришло время волшебства.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $х=0;
for (my $x=0; $x<3; ++$х) {
    print $х."\n";
}
```

[Проверить на ideone.com](http://ideone.com/zHFVV8) (добавил ограничение до 100)

Comment: А где разоблачение магии? :)

Comment: @VladD было бы эгоистично с моей стороны сразу же добавлять пояснения к такому небольшому примеру, тем самым лишая возможности  подумать остальным. А так, позднее добавим конечно, если этого не сделают раньше.

Comment: @VladD, наверняка что-то связанное с областью видимости переменной $x объявленного до цикла и внутри

Comment: @Grundy: думаю, даже не внутри цикла, после первого `;` в `for` :-\

Comment: Сразу догадался про кириллический `х` по `use utf8;` Это нарушает требование на работоспособность в чистой программе: `my $z=0;
for (my $x=0; $x<3; ++$z) {
    print $z."\n";
}`: сам по себе `for (my $x=0; $x<3; ++$z)` не будет исполняться 3 раза.

Comment: Кстати, ideone ещё и подсвечивает их по-разному. Впрочем, я туда даже не заходил, когда догадался.