# Заменить в строке-шаблоне набор подстрок, сгенерировать все варианты сочетаний, не выходит придумать алгоритм

Tags: массивы, строки, замена

Я мог бы попытаться объяснить на пальцах, но скорее всего лишь больше запутаю всех. Давайте просто покажу что нужно:

Нужно: функция возвращающая массив строк, принимающая два параметра: массив строк и строку-шаблон.

Входящие данные:

> ['x4','d9','z5']
>   'test x4 for d9 word z5 eleven'

Результат:

> [
>    'test x4 for d9 word z5 eleven',
>    'test x4 for d9 word 00 eleven',
>    'test x4 for 00 word z5 eleven',
>    'test x4 for 00 word 00 eleven',
>    'test 00 for d9 word z5 eleven',
>    'test 00 for d9 word 00 eleven',
>    'test 00 for 00 word z5 eleven',
>    'test 00 for 00 word 00 eleven'
>   ]

Данные взял от балды, количество строк входящего массива может быть любым, содержание тоже, и шаблон тоже любой текст. Заменяется на 00 - это пока на данный момент задаётся как строка-константа.

Я не понимаю по какому принципу тут следует действовать, рекурсию может, но никак не соображу алгоритм...

З.Ы. Задание выдумал себе сам.

Answer (score 0):

Короче как-то так, вроде работает:

```
function processCombinations(params, i, template, variants) {
    if (i >= 0) {
        if (i < params.length) {
            processCombinations(params, i+1, template, variants);
            processCombinations(params, i+1, template.replace(params[i], '00'), variants);
        } else {
            variants.push(template);
        }
    }
...
var params = ['x4', 'd9', 'z5'];
var template = 'test x4 for d9 word z5 eleven';
var result = [];
processCombinations(params, 0, template, result);
alert(result.join('\n'));
```

Comment: А возможно ли без рекурсии переписать?

Comment: Язык то какой? Ну и в целом не совсем понял, что вы хотите сделать. Если это тупо задачка на рекомбинацию элементов массива, то загляните в последний код-гольф http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581668/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9, там есть несколько вариантов без рекурсии

Comment: Любой. От си/паскаля до шарпа и браузерных скриптов. Мне сам алгоритм в голову никак не приходил.
Конкретно это на JS наваял. Спасибо большое, посмотрю.

Comment: Дал же пример входящих/результирующих данных... Я не знаю как это научно обозвать...

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно протелепатировал суть.

Использую PHP

1. Разбиваем строку на массив слов
2. Составляем карту расположения заменяемых слов (массив с ключами массива из первого пункта)
3. В цикле перебираем все возможные битовые маски для карты (2 пункт)
4. В соответствии с битовой маской заменяем в исходной строке те элементы, для которых в маске установлен бит 1

## код

```
<?php
$blank='1';
$pattern=['x40', 'd9', 'z5'];
$string='test x40 for d9 word z5 eleven';
$exploded=explode(' ',$string);
$map=[];

foreach($pattern as $seq) $map = array_merge(array_keys($exploded, $seq), $map);

for($mask=0;$mask<1<<count($map);$mask++){
    $current=$exploded;
    foreach($map as $key=>$value)
        if(1<<$key&$mask) $current[$value] = $blank;
    echo implode(' ',$current).PHP_EOL;
}
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e611c935e3660afb62b2865ddd623039aa78fa1a)

PS Конечно тут еще много подводных камней, связанных в основном с правильным определением карты заменяемых последовательностей. Они могут пересекаться, быть частью слова и т.д.

Comment: Интересное решение! Спасибо большое!