# Как разделить массив на несколько частей сбалансированно?

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм

Например:

```
$groups = [
    ['name' => 'Group 1', 'items' => [1]],
    ['name' => 'Group 2', 'items' => [1,2]],
    ['name' => 'Group 3', 'items' => [1,2,3,4,5,6]],
    ['name' => 'Group 4', 'items' => [1,2,3]],
    ['name' => 'Group 5', 'items' => [5,6]],
    ['name' => 'Group 6', 'items' => [5]],
];
```

Должен разделиться на массивы содержащие примерно одинаковое число элементов.
Если пополам, то:

```
[
        [
            ['name' => 'Group 1', 'items' => [1]],
            ['name' => 'Group 2', 'items' => [1,2]],
            ['name' => 'Group 4', 'items' => [1,2,3]],
            ['name' => 'Group 5', 'items' => [5,6]],
        ],
        [
            ['name' => 'Group 3', 'items' => [1,2,3,4,5,6]],
            ['name' => 'Group 6', 'items' => [5]],
        ] 
];
```

Это удобно, когда выводишь списки в колонки (например, меню), и надо, чтобы не образовывались пустые области.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581668/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9/583446#583446  Если кратко, то число элементов - это вес массива. Вам надо найти комбинацию, которая в сумме даст половину общего веса. (ну или +-1, если общий вес нечетный)

Comment: _Если пополам, то_ - что-то фиговенький пополам получился, в первой группе 8 элементов, а во второй 6...

Comment: @Akina во второй 7.

Comment: Ну тады ладноть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическая задача о рюкзаке.

Поскольку предметная область не требует непременно оптимальное решение, можно попробовать жадный алгоритм. Т.е. вектор количества элементов в массиве сортируем по убыванию и начинаем раскладывать в два (или больше - смотря на сколько частей нужно поделить) вектора, кладя очередной элемент в тот вектор, где на текущий момент сумма меньше.