# Индекс элемента при выводе массива через диапазонный цикл for

Tags: c++, c++11

У меня есть простейший Range-based цикл:

```
int arr[3] = { 9, 7, 1 };
for (auto i: arr) std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Программа выведет на экран содержимое массива:

```
9
7
1
```

А если я хочу вывести на экран более подробную информацию:

```
массив[0] = 9
массив[1] = 7
массив[2] = 1
```

Как мне обойтись без введения дополнительной переменной-счетчика? или это невозможно?

Comment: Обычный `for (;;)` в помощь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Получить индекс элемента внутри range-for можно, но для этого надо изменить тип переменной:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int arr[3] = { 9, 7, 1 };
    for (auto& v: arr) std::cout << (&v - &arr[0]) << "-" <<  v << "\n";
}
```

[Вывод:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/K8T6JW5PDerVUm9i)

> ```
> 0-9   
> 1-7   
> 2-1
> ```

Здесь мы добавили `&` к `auto`, чтобы тип итерируемой переменной был `int&`. Т.о. переменная цикла это не новая копия, а ссылка на элемент массива. И т.к. элементы массива расположены в памяти последовательно, то выражение `(&v - &arr[0])` в данном случае будет давать смещение элемента от начала массива, т.е. по сути необходимый Вам индекс.

Можно заметить, что дополнительную переменную вводить для этого не пришлось, как утверждали другие участники.

Comment: а если arr это `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @KoVadim логично, что код немного [изменится](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iGeWmVVO1ywtP8dY).

Comment: а если там нечаяно станет `std::list<int>` ?

Comment: @KoVadim, тогда `std::distance` — наше всё. С любовью, искренне ваш маляр Шлемиэль.

Comment: @KoVadim в вопросе ТС массив, мой ответ на вопрос ТС. А что если он его сейчас изменит? Мне нужно будет удалить ответ или корректировать его? Поэтому не надо строить предположений, я не обещал работоспособный вариант для всех контейнеров. Именно потому, что в вопросе был исключительно массив.

Comment: ну, уже пришлось скорректировать код ТС:)

Comment: @KoVadim давайте не будет опускаться до абсурда, а то и `"i"` оставить пришлось бы.

Comment: @KoVadim, вот вектор: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586593/178988

Comment: @Arhad: Впросы, конечно, абсурдные, но тем не менее `std::distance` здесь никак не поможет.

Comment: @AnT, почему? `for (auto& v: arr) std::cout << std::distance(&arr[0], &v) << '-' <<  v << '\n';`. В отличие от оператора вычитания, `distance` имеет шаблонную перегрузку для контейнеров без непрерывного хранения.

Comment: @Arhad: `std::distance` требует *итераторы* на вход, а не указатели на элементы контейнера. Для `std::vector` (как в вашем примере) это сработает, по очевидным причинам. Ни для какого другого контейнера это, разумеется, работать не будет, пока вы не найдете способа конвертировать указатели на элементы в итераторы. Прямой конверсии в общем случае не существует, по каковой причине `std::distance` тут ничем помочь не может.

Comment: А по-моему это самый правильный ответ на данный вопрос. Как раз что хотел ТС. И подход оригинальный.

Comment: @Isaev: "Самый правильный ответ" - это не использовать range-based for в ситуациях, когда нужен индекс или итератор текущего элемента. То, что предлагается в этом ответе, приемлемо в отладочных целях, но не более того.

Comment: @AnT ну это уже другая сторона медали, естественно, что эта конструкция для того и была создана, но для общего развития и уталения любопытства очень даже полезно

Answer (score 8):

Очевидно, в этом предложении

```
for (auto i: arr) std::cout << "i" << "\n";
                              ^^^^
```

вы допустили опечатку. Скорей всего вы имели в виду

```
for (auto i: arr) std::cout << i << "\n";
                              ^^^^
```

Что касается вашего вопроса, то чтобы дополнительно к значениям элементов массива получить значения индексов элементов массива, вам в любом случае придется вводить дополнительную переменную.

Поэтому в таких случаях лучше использовать обычное `for` предложение.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ); i++ )
{
    std::cout << arr[i] << "\n";
}
```

Циклы на основе диапазона для того и введены, чтобы освободиться от переменной, которая обычно при выводе значений массива не нужна. Использование переменной для хранения индексов часто является причиной многочисленных ошибок либо когда индексирование начинают не с 0, а, например, с 1, или когда указывают неправильно верхнее значение диапазона индексов.

Answer (score 6):

В дополнение к и так полному ответу [@Vlad from Moscow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183394/vlad-from-moscow) - на случай использования других контейнеров учтите, что понятие индексов применимо не ко всем контейнерам. Так что способ вывода, например,

```
int arr[3] = { 9, 7, 1 };
int i = 0;
for (auto n: arr) 
{
    std::cout << "arr[" << i++ << "] = " << n << "\n";
}
```

Который в принципе сработает для массивов или векторов (и то не уверен, гарантирует ли это стандарт), для многих контейнеров не подойдет - например, для хэш-таблиц порядок размещения вообще никак не определен, для множеств - они всегда упорядочены.

Comment: кроме встроенного массива и std::vector , индексацию можно применять и для std::deque - последовательный контейнер хранящий данные блоками по `k` элементов образующие связный список