# Задача на алгоритм выборки комбинаций

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Не понимаю способа решения данной задачи. Помогите, прошу, натолкните на путь истинный.

> Однажды мама попросила Петю сходить в магазин и купить ровно
>   n фруктов. Придя в магазин он увидел, что может купить яблоки, бананы, апельсины и айву. Но он не может купить произвольное количество каждого вида фруктов:
>
> - Бананы продаются гроздьями по 5 бананов в каждой, поэтому их количество должно быть кратно пяти.
> - Петя и его сестра одинаково сильно любят яблоки, поэтому количество яблок должно быть чётным.
> - Апельсинов в магазине осталось всего 4 штуки.
> - Петя не очень любит айву, поэтому не будет покупать больше одной.
>
> Посчитайте, сколько всего различных способов купить n фруктов есть у Пети.
>   Входные данные:
>   Единственная строка содержит одно целое число n(1⩽n⩽109) — количество фруктов. Результат
>   Нужно вывести одно число — количество способов купить n фруктов.

Comment: Минусаторам: тут совсем не нужно решать задачу за автора. Объясните алгоритм на псевдокоде, этого будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: Андрей, вас же устроит просто объяснение алгоритма решения?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Конечно устроит. Буду рад его увидеть!

Comment: Похоже на эту задачу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581668/581750  только предположить что во входном массиве лежит несколько раз по минимальному количеству фруктов каждого вида, только 1 т.е. айву только 1 раз. и конечно массива никакого делать не надо а укладывать по мере необходимости. И видимо начинать с минимальной корзины, где сразу лежит каждый вид по 1 разу, если задача купить все виды обязательно (в условиях этого вроде как не сказано, но возможно подразумевается)

Comment: @АндрейСухой отлично, тогда чуток поменяю метки.

Comment: @АндрейСухой кстати, http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#grovelling

Comment: Ответ оказался просто к входному числу прибавить 1 и вывести :D

Comment: @Mike, 4 апельсина! :D

Comment: @АндрейСухой Сделал тестовую программку для перебора, действительно строго +1. Хотелось бы понять математический смысл этого :)  Вы там где узнали про +1 случайно не нашли доказательства или объяснения принципов. Написали бы ответом ... А так в принципе перебор то же элементарный вышел https://ideone.com/oz2Pui

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, мы здесь имеем дело с т.н. сочетаниями с повторениями.
Количество сочетаний с повторениями вычисляется по следующей формуле:

[image: С n по k с повторениями]

Для 109 это будет 227920 сочетаний. Число не астрономическое, можно перебирать их все и считать те, которые отвечают условиям задачи. Но делать этого мы всё-таки не будем.

Мы разделим задачу на ряд мелких. Для этого нам понадобятся 4 вложенных цикла со счётчиком. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
s = 0  # количество возможных сочетаний

for x in range(0,2):  # x - количество айвы
    if (n-x) < 4 : max_o = n - x  # проверим, сколько апельсинов поместится в нашу покупку 
    else: max_o = 4 
    for o in range(0,max_o+1):  # o - количество апельсинов
        for a in range(0,n-x-o+1,2):  # a - количество яблок. Счётчик прибавляет по 2 яблока за шаг!
            if (n-x-o-a) % 5 == 0: s += 1 # Мы выполнили три условия.
                                          # Но делится ли оставшееся место на 5 (кратность количества бананов)? 
                                          # Если да, то мы выполнили все условия и можем засчитать это сочетание.
```

Разумеется, порядок вложенности циклов можно изменять как угодно.
Главное - сохранять суть алгоритма: 3 условия выполняем, 1 проверяем.

Comment: Раз вы уж формулу привели, может вы хоть скажете, почему при данных условиях задачи количество сочетаний получается _всегда_ на 1 больше требуемого количества фруктов и вся программа сводится к `print(n+1)` ?

Comment: Насчёт n+1 нужно немного подумать. Я не запускал код, поэтому не заметил. Спасибо.